# How can I pretty-print JSON using node.js?

Tags: json, node.js

This seems like a solved problem but I am unable to find a solution for it.

Basically, I read a JSON file, change a key, and write back the new JSON to the same file. All works, but I loose the JSON formatting.So, instead of:

```
{
  name:'test',
  version:'1.0'
}
```

I get

```
{name:'test',version:'1.1'}
```

Is there a way in Node.js to write well formatted JSON to file ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` chokes on cyclic objects, and `util.inspect` doesn't produce valid json. :\ I found no [native] solution to pretty printing JSON in NodeJS

Comment: @ThorSummoner: That is a problem with JSON, not with Node—JSON does not natively support cyclic references. There is a solution [here, in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382383/104184).

Answer (score 1116, accepted):

`JSON.stringify`'s third parameter defines white-space insertion for pretty-printing. It can be a string or a number (number of spaces). Node can write to your filesystem with `fs`.  Example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('test.json', JSON.stringify({ a:1, b:2, c:3 }, null, 4));
/* test.json:
{
     "a": 1,
     "b": 2,
     "c": 3,
}
*/
```

See the [JSON.stringify() docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), [Node fs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Comment: Note : instead of 4, use `"\t"` if you want tabs.

Comment: In latest nodejs you need to provide a callback function as third parameter, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11677276/675065

Comment: @Alp means the third parameter of `fs.writeFile`; you don't actually have to use the callback if the write is the last command in your script. You only need the callback if you want to do something after `writeFile`, other than exit the process.

Answer (score 242):

I think this might be useful... I love example code :)

```
var fs = require('fs');

var myData = {
  name:'test',
  version:'1.0'
}

var outputFilename = '/tmp/my.json';

fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4), function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFilename);
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure the `tmp` folder exist or else this might fail.

Comment: in most unix systems (including Mac & Linux..and if I recall BSD), `tmp` folder exists by default

Comment: what is the location(Output filename) to be given in case of windows

Comment: I don't know why my file didn't get written (just opened empty) without the callback... Or maybe it's async, and it didn't work because I had an exception thrown while app startup?

Comment: @TomaszGandor: All I/O in Node is async by default, so the `writeFile` call doesn't block the program. If you don't pass a callback, Node doesn't have any more code to run, so it exits immediately after the call, likely before the actual write finished.

Answer (score 123):

If you just want to pretty print an object and not export it as valid JSON you can use `console.dir()`.

It uses syntax-highlighting, smart indentation, removes quotes from keys and just makes the output as pretty as it gets.

```
const jsonString = `{"name":"John","color":"green",
                     "smoker":false,"id":7,"city":"Berlin"}`
const object = JSON.parse(jsonString)

console.dir(object, {depth: null, colors: true})
```

[image: Screenshot of logged object]

Under the hood it is a shortcut for `console.log(util.inspect(…))`.
The only difference is that it bypasses any custom `inspect()` function defined on an object.

Comment: console.dir doesn't produce valid json.

Comment: @GreggLind Clarified that in the answer!

Comment: This made my express server stall. I don't know why :(

Answer (score 56):

If you don't want to store this anywhere, but just view the object for debugging purposes.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, "  "));
```

You can change the third parameter to adjust the indentation.

Comment: I've been looking for this solution -like for ever!  The last param works like a charm!

Answer (score 40):

I know this is old question. But maybe this can help you

### JSON string

```js
var jsonStr = '{ "bool": true, "number": 123, "string": "foo bar" }';
```

### Pretty Print JSON

```js
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonStr), null, 2);
```

### Minify JSON

```js
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
```

Answer (score 30):

what about this?

```
console.table(object)
```

[image: sample]

Comment: this is a good solution for small datasets, but for large, complex, deeply nested objects it's essentially impossible to read with all the line wrapping. there might be a solution to that too I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround would be to make use of prettier to format the JSON.
The example below is using 'json' parser but it could also use 'json5', see [list of valid parsers](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser).

```
const prettier = require("prettier");
console.log(prettier.format(JSON.stringify(object),{ semi: false, parser: "json" }));
```

Answer (score -1):

if prettify is name value pairs on new lines then specifying number of spaces in stringify didn't work for me the only thing that worked for me was

```
await fs.promises.writeFile('testdataattr.json',JSON.stringify(datatofile, null,'\r\n'),'utf8') ;
```