# How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '[Object]'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, console.log

I have this object:

```
const myObject = {
   "a":"a",
   "b":{
      "c":"c",
      "d":{
         "e":"e",
         "f":{
            "g":"g",
            "h":{
               "i":"i"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
```

But when I try to show it using `console.log(myObject)`, I receive this output:

```
{ a: 'a', b: { c: 'c', d: { e: 'e', f: [Object] } } }
```

How can I get the full object, including the content of property `f`?

Comment: Note that back in 2012 this was a problem in need of a solution, but this has (long) since been solved with the introduction of `console.dir`, which takes an options object that lets you specify the printing depth, with `null` for unlimited depth: `console.dir(yourObject, { depth: null });`. The highest voted answers for this question were all great answers back when they were written, but have since become obsolete over the course of a decade of improvements. The modern answer is simply  "use `console.dir`".

Comment: I guess a best practice for StackOverflow users would be to use "Sorted by: Date modified (newest first)" if a question is old enough. Answer from mklement0 also suggests to use `console.dir`

Answer (score 2212, accepted):

You need to use [`util.inspect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

```
const util = require('util')

console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null, colors: true}))

// alternative shortcut
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
```

Outputs

```
{ a: 'a',  b: { c: 'c', d: { e: 'e', f: { g: 'g', h: { i: 'i' } } } } }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Though no need to specify {showHidden: false} as long as it defaults to false.

Comment: Good to know; not sure when it was introduced, but as of at least node `v0.10.33` `console.log()` _implicitly_ applies `util.inspect()` to its arguments, assuming the 1st one is not a format string. If you're happy with `util.inspect()`'s default options, simply `console.log(myObject)` will do - no need to require `util`; `console.dir()` does the same, but accepts only ` object to inspect; as of at least `v0.11.14`, you can pass the options object for `util.inspect()` as the 2nd argument; my answer has more details.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: "`console.dir()` does the same, but accepts only \` object to inspect" should have been "... accepts only _one_ object to inspect".

Comment: If you need it for "generators" and use the output in code: Be careful: It seems util.inspect doesn't quote sensitive Object.keys. Tested with {in: 'i'}

Comment: @mklement0 I have node v5.3.0 and when I `console.log(obj)` it still prints [Object] for deeply nested objects :( I really wish it would behave as you describe.

Comment: @SSH: `console.log()` is _invariably_ limited to _2_ levels (because it uses `util.inspect()`'s default without allowing you to change it); `console.dir()` has the same limit by default, but you can pass in an options object as the 2nd argument to change that (which is passed through to `util.inspect()`; note that `console.dir()`  can only ever print _1_ object at a time, however. To print with unlimited depth, use `console.dir(myObject, { depth: null })`.

Comment: How can I console.log() it into client console making it collapsible? I mean the fold/unfold feature to open close its children

Comment: definitively `util.inspect` is the right solution. See here for all options, styles and colors as well! https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: `console.dir(myObject, { depth: null })` is work for me

Comment: @VeckHsiao has the best comment, and it is in the community answer below.  `console.dir(myObject, { depth: 4, colors: true }` for instance is what I use.  Easier than `util.inspect` and has the same output with keeping small objects/arrays on one line and providing class names, function references with their names, etc), and syntax highlighting...

Comment: This is a great one for AWS CloudWatch which tends to break console.dir and other loggers into individual lines, which it doesn't do for console.log.

Comment: @VeckHsiao: `console.dir(mongooseObject, { depth: null })` prints far less than `console.log(util.inspect(mongooseObject, {depth: null}))`, so they're not always equivalent.

Comment: today 2022, I tried to use `console.dir` with the `brackets {yourObjHere}` like so `console.dir({yourObjectHere},{depth:null})` it created an object and made its format a little easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 961):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and get some nice indentation as well as perhaps easier to remember syntax.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 4));
```

---

```
{
    "a": "a",
    "b": {
        "c": "c",
        "d": {
            "e": "e",
            "f": {
                "g": "g",
                "h": {
                    "i": "i"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The third argument sets the indentation level, so you can adjust that as desired.

More detail here in [JSON stringify MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) if needed.

Comment: also +1 for line breaks and indentation - almost always desired for me personally

Comment: Note that you cannot JSON.stringify objects with _circular references_. Like it would occur with DOM objects, for example. Stringify will throw an "Error: Converting circular structure to JSON".

Comment: this isn't the full object. objects containing only functions will be {}. Of course that may be a positive or a negative depending on what you want to print out.

Comment: @IgnacioLago So what's the solution for that situation?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is ok, but consider that only works on `json` structures. If you want to output a javascript object, this will not work in all cases, while `util.inspect` will. Also, to avoid `...more items` of console.log you need to pass to `util.inspect` the `{ maxArrayLength: 1000 }` option, in this case to print up to 1000 items in any case.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 4));` pretty cool! [https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/92aa2b00249f15084d24aa2e0a5d0300](https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms-GitHub/92aa2b00249f15084d24aa2e0a5d0300)

Comment: In my case i get this error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: It loses its color.

Comment: I don't like amount of quotes in the output.

Comment: This was the solution that finally worked, thank you! `JSON.stringify` with all params, but I will look into `util.inspect` also, based on @loretoparisi's comment

Answer (score 816):

<sup>A compilation of the many useful answers from (at least) Node.js `v0.10.33` (stable) / `v0.11.14` (unstable) presumably through (at least) `v7.7.4` (the version current as of the latest update to this answer). Tip of the hat to [Rory O'Kane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578288/rory-okane) for his help.</sup>

**tl;dr**

To get the desired output for the example in the question, use [`console.dir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options):

```
console.dir(myObject, { depth: null }); // `depth: null` ensures unlimited recursion
```

Why not `util.inspect()`? Because it’s already at the heart of diagnostic output: `console.log()` and `console.dir()` as well as the Node.js REPL **use `util.inspect()` *implicitly***. It’s generally ***not* necessary to `require('util')`** and call `util.inspect()` directly - *unless* you want to capture the object visualization *in a variable* rather than printing to the console (e.g., `let s = util.inspect(myObject, { depth: null })`)

Details below.

---

- [**`console.log()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) (and its alias, [`console.info()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_info_data_args)):

  - **If the 1st argument is NOT a format string**: [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) is automatically applied to every argument:

    - `o = { one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: function(){} }; console.log(o, [1,2,3]) // ->  '{ one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: [Function] } [ 1, 2, 3 ]'`
    - Note that you **cannot pass options** through `util.inspect()` in this case, which implies 2 notable limitations:

      - Structural **depth** of the output is **limited to *2* levels** (the default).

        - Since you cannot change this with `console.log()`, you must instead use `console.dir()`: **`console.dir(myObject, { depth: null }` prints with *unlimited* depth**; see below.
      - You can’t turn syntax coloring on.
  - **If the 1st argument IS a format string** (see below): uses [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) to print the remaining arguments based on the format string (see below); e.g.:

    - `o = { one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: function(){} }; console.log('o as JSON: %j', o) // ->  'o as JSON: {"one":1,"two":"deux"}'`
    - Note:

      - There is NO placeholder for representing *objects* `util.inspect()`-style.
      - JSON generated with `%j` is NOT pretty-printed.
- [**`console.dir()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options):

  - **Accepts only *1* argument to inspect**, and always applies [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) – essentially, a wrapper for `util.inspect()` without options by default; e.g.:

    - `o = { one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: function(){} }; console.dir(o); // Effectively the same as console.log(o) in this case.`
  - **Node.js v0.11.14+**: The optional 2nd argument specifies **options for `util.inspect()`** – see below; e.g.:

    - `console.dir({ one: 1, two: 'deux'}, { colors: true }); // Node 0.11+: Prints object representation with syntax coloring.`

- **The REPL**: **implicitly prints any expression's return value with `util.inspect()` *with*  syntax coloring**;
  i.e., just typing a variable's name and hitting Enter will print an inspected version of its value; e.g.:

  - `o = { one: 1, two: 'deux', foo: function(){} }  // The REPL echoes the object definition with syntax coloring.`

**[`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) automatically pretty-prints *object* and *array* representations**, but produces ***multiline* output only when needed**.

- The pretty-printing behavior can be controlled by the `compact` property in the optional `options` argument; `false` uses multi-line output *unconditionally*, whereas `true` disables pretty-printing altogether; it can also be set to a *number* (the default is `3`) to control the conditional multi-line behavior – see [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).
- By default, output is wrapped [at around 60 characters](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L815) <sup>thanks, [Shrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2248009/shrey)</sup>
  , regardless of whether the output is sent to a file or a terminal. In practice, since *line breaks only happen at property boundaries*, you will often end up with shorter lines, but they can also be longer (e.g., with long property values).
- In v6.3.0+ you can use the `breakLength` option to override the 60-character limit; if you set it to `Infinity`, everything is output on a *single* line.

**If you want more control over pretty-printing, consider using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with a 3rd argument**, but note the following:

- *Fails* with objects that have *circular references*, such as `module` in the global context.
- *Methods* (functions) will by design NOT be included.
- You can't opt into showing hidden (non-enumerable) properties.
- Example call:

  - `JSON.stringify({ one: 1, two: 'deux', three: true}, undefined, 2); // creates a pretty-printed multiline JSON representation indented with 2 spaces`

---

**[`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) options object** (2nd argument):

An optional *options* object may be passed that alters certain aspects of the formatted string; *some* of the properties supported are:

<sup>See [the latest Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) for the current, full list.</sup>

- `showHidden`

  - if `true`,  then the object's non-enumerable properties [those designated not to show up when you use `for keys in obj` or `Object.keys(obj)`] will be shown too. Defaults to `false`.
- `depth`

  - tells inspect how many times to recurse while formatting the object. This is useful for inspecting large complicated objects. Defaults to 2. To make it recurse indefinitely, pass `null`.
- `colors`

  - if true, then the output will be styled with ANSI color codes. Defaults to `false`. Colors are customizable [… – see link].
- `customInspect`

  - if `false`, then custom `inspect()` functions defined on the objects being inspected won't be called. Defaults to `true`.

---

**[`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) format-string placeholders** (1st argument)

*Some* of the supported placeholders are:

<sup>See [the latest Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) for the current, full list.</sup>

- `%s` – String.
- `%d` – Number (both integer and float).
- `%j` – JSON.
- `%%` – single percent sign (‘%’). This does not consume an argument.

Comment: One way to simplify this would be to do a small named function to do `console.dir(...)` without all the typing: `show = (v, depth=null)=> console.dir(v,{depth:depth})` and then call it like so `show(variable)` or `show(variable, depth=1)`.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer => THE BEST SOLUTION YOU GAVE  : JSON.stringify({ one: 1, two: 'deux', three: true}, undefined, 2);

Comment: `undefined` also works: `console.dir(myObject, { depth: undefined })`

Comment: How do you save console.dir output into a string?

Comment: @minseong, use `util.inspect()`, e.g. `let s = util.inspect(myObject, { depth: null })`; I've also updated the answer with this information.

Answer (score 77):

Since Node.js 6.4.0, this can be elegantly solved with [`util.inspect.defaultOptions`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_defaultoptions):

```
require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;
console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 73):

Another simple method is to convert it to json

```
console.log('connection : %j', myObject);
```

Comment: Nice trick but the output won't be prettified, which makes it hard to read for large objects (the point of the question).

Comment: still very useful, and quicker to copy and paste into http://jsonlint.com/ than requiring `utils` :)

Comment: I think this one is great when you have an editor that will format json for you but you just need to copy it out from REPL

Comment: This is very handy and helpful if the object is small

Answer (score 68):

Try this:

```
console.dir(myObject,{depth:null})
```

Answer (score 32):

Both of these usages can be applied:

```
// more compact, and colour can be applied (better for process managers logging)
console.dir(queryArgs, { depth: null, colors: true });

// get a clear list of actual values
console.log(JSON.stringify(queryArgs, undefined, 2));
```

Answer (score 29):

perhaps `console.dir` is all you need.

http://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj

> Uses util.inspect on obj and prints resulting string to stdout.

use util option if you need more control.

Comment: [console.dir is buggy and doesn't yet pass on the `options` object to `util.inspect`.](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/7754)

Comment: As of (at least) v0.11.14, you can pass an options object as the 2nd argument, which is passed to `util.inspect()`.

Answer (score 26):

A good way to inspect objects is to use node **--inspect** option with **Chrome DevTools for Node**.

```
node.exe --inspect www.js
```

Open `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome and click **Open dedicated DevTools for Node**

Now every logged object is available in inspector like regular JS running in chrome.

[image]

There is no need to reopen inspector, it connects to node automatically as soon as node starts or restarts. Both **--inspect** and **Chrome DevTools for Node** may not be available in older versions of Node and Chrome.

Comment: A message for me: try that out -> `node.exe --inspect index.js`

Comment: This should be on top. best answer. :)

Answer (score 21):

You can also do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 3));
```

Answer (score 13):

I think this could be useful for you.

```js
const myObject = {
   "a":"a",
   "b":{
      "c":"c",
      "d":{
         "e":"e",
         "f":{
            "g":"g",
            "h":{
               "i":"i"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, '\t'));
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670892):

> `JSON.stringify`'s third parameter defines white-space insertion for
>   pretty-printing. It can be a string or a number (number of spaces).

Answer (score 9):

## Use a logger

> Don't try to reinvent the wheel

`util.inspect()`, `JSON.stringify()` and `console.dir()` are useful tools for logging an object while playing in the browser console.

If you are *serious* about Node.js development, you should definitely use a logger. Using it you can add all the logs you want for **debugging and monitoring** your application. Then just **change the logging level** of your logger to keep only the production logs **visible**.

Additionaly they have already solved all the annoying issues related to logging, like: **circular objects**, **formatting**, log **levels**, multiple **outputs** and  **performance**.

### Use a modern logger

[`pino`](https://getpino.io/) is a [fast](https://getpino.io/#/docs/benchmarks) and modern logger for Node.js that has sane defaults to handle circular object/references like [`depthLimit`](https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=depthlimit-number) and [`edgeLimit`](https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=edgelimit-number). It supports [child loggers](https://getpino.io/#/docs/child-loggers), [transports](https://getpino.io/#/docs/transports) and a [pretty printed](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty) output.

Moreover, it has 8 default logging levels that you can customize using the [`customLevels` option](https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=opt-customlevels):

- `fatal`
- `error`
- `warn`
- `info`
- `debug`
- `trace`
- `silent`

### Install it

```
npm install pino
```

### Use it

```
const logger = require('pino')()

logger.info('hello world')
```

### Configure it

```
const logger = pino({
  depthLimit: 10,
  edgeLimit: 200,
  customLevels: {
    foo: 35
  }
});

logger.foo('hi')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply add an `inspect()` method to your object which will override the representation of object in `console.log` messages

eg:

```
var myObject = {
   "a":"a",
   "b":{
      "c":"c",
      "d":{
         "e":"e",
         "f":{
            "g":"g",
            "h":{
               "i":"i"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
myObject.inspect = function(){ return JSON.stringify( this, null, ' ' ); }
```

then, your object will be represented as required in both console.log and node shell

---

Update:

object.inspect has been deprecated ( https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15549). Use myObject[util.inspect.custom] instead:

```
const util = require('util')

var myObject = {
  /* nested properties not shown */
}

myObject[util.inspect.custom] = function(){ return JSON.stringify( this, null, 4 ); }


console.log(util.inspect(myObject))
```

Answer (score 8):

## JSON.stringify()

```
let myVar = {a: {b: {c: 1}}};
console.log(JSON.stringify( myVar, null, 4 ))
```

Great for deep inspection of data objects. This approach works on nested arrays and nested objects with arrays.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a way to show the hidden items in you array, you got to pass `maxArrayLength: Infinity`

```
console.log(util.inspect(value, { maxArrayLength: Infinity }));
```

Comment: Also works with `console.dir`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple trick would be use `debug` module to add `DEBUG_DEPTH=null` as environment variable when running the script

Ex.

DEBUG=* DEBUG_DEPTH=null node index.js

In you code

```
const debug = require('debug');
debug("%O", myObject);
```

Comment: @Bala You  will need to install "debug" module in your project
"npm install debug --save"

Answer (score 4):

```
const myObject = {
   "a":"a",
   "b":{
      "c":"c",
      "d":{
         "e":"e",
         "f":{
            "g":"g",
            "h":{
               "i":"i"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Output:

```
{"a":"a","b":{"c":"c","d":{"e":"e","f":{"g":"g","h":{"i":"i"}}}}}
```

Comment: Warning: JSON.stringify has limitations:
- can't display all variable types: functions, Symbol, BigInt...
- crashes on circular references

Answer (score 3):

Easiest option:

```js
    console.log('%O', myObject);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of printing `myObject` to an arbitrary depth

Answer (score 2):

The node REPL has a built-in solution for overriding how objects are displayed, see [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/repl.html#repl_customizing_object_displays_in_the_repl).

> The REPL module internally uses `util.inspect()`, when printing values.
>   However, `util.inspect` delegates the call to the object's `inspect()`
>   function, if it has one.