# Node to parse xml using xml2js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse and query for an element within an xml using xml2js. My xml string is as follows:

```
var xml = "<config><test>Hello</test><data>SomeData</data></config>";
```

What I want is to extract the value in  and assign it to `var extractedData`

Here's what I have so far:

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
parser.parseString(xml, function(err,result){
  //Extract the value from the data element
  extractedData = result['data'];
}
```

This does not work. Can somebody point out how I might be able to grab the values from my xml?

Thanks

This doesn't seem to be working. Can somebody tell me what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

it works for me

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml = "<config><test>Hello</test><data>SomeData</data></config>";

var extractedData = "";
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
parser.parseString(xml, function(err,result){
  //Extract the value from the data element
  extractedData = result['config']['data'];
  console.log(extractedData);
});
console.log("Note that you can't use value here if parseString is async; extractedData=", extractedData);
```

result:

```
SomeData
Note that you can't use value here if parseString is async; extractedData= SomeData
```

Comment: How can I print data which is in 5 or 6 level of depth

Comment: @Vishwanathgowdak use `util.inspect()`; see the accepted answer here for a quick example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-js-console-log-rather-than-object  Here's a quick and dirty approach: `console.log(require('util').inspect(result, false, null));`