# How to print JSON data in console.log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I cant access JSON data from javascript. Please help me how to access data from JSON data in javascript.

i have a JSON data like

```
{"success":true,"input_data":{"quantity-row_122":"1","price-row_122":" 35.1 "}}
```

i have tried console.log(data) but log print object object

```
success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
}
```

How to print console.log particular data?
I need to print

```
quantity-row_122 = 1
price-row_122 = 35.1
```

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(data) to convert it into string ang then try to print.

Comment: 4 same answers within 1 minute, I guess this solution was obvious :P

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` is the simplest answer, but if you want something more fancy you can use `console-log-json` from the NPM repository:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-log-json

Answer (score 94):

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` will do what you need. I'm assuming that you're using jQuery based on your code.

If you're wanting those two particular values, you can just access those and pass them to `log`.

```
console.log(data.input_data['quantity-row_122']); 
console.log(data.input_data['price-row_122']);
```

Comment: this works good but 'quantity-row_122' field are generated dynamically and it comes from html form.so what we can do?  so i want to print as like array

Comment: Need to quote those 2 key names

Comment: Why not use `console.log("%j", something)`?

Comment: This is the simplest answer.  But If you want something more fancy you can use `console-log-json` from the NPM repository: https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-log-json

Answer (score 64):

I used '%j' option in console.log to print JSON objects

```
console.log("%j", jsonObj);
```

Comment: Best answers of all.

Comment: I'm getting console log as: [Circular]

Comment: Love this.  Works great.

Answer (score 34):

To output an object to the console, you have to stringify the object first:

```
success:function(data){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 30):

I usually do like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4));
```

Comment: What is the number 4 for?

Comment: The number 4 represents how many spaces to indent per level of depth each output line is. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#space).

Answer (score 26):

```
{"success":true,"input_data":{"quantity-row_122":"1","price-row_122":" 35.1 "}}
```

`console.dir()` will do what you need. It will give you a hierarchical structure of the data.

```
success:function(data){
     console.dir(data);
}
```

like so

```
> Object
  > input_data: Object
      price-row_122: " 35.1 "
      quantity-row_122: "1"
    success: true
```

I don't think you need `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`.

To get the data you can do this without `stringify`:

```
console.log(data.success); // true
console.log(data.input_data['quantity-row_122']) // "1"
console.log(data.input_data['price-row_122']) // " 35.1 "
```

**Note**

The value from `input_data` Object will be `typeof "1"`: `String`, but you can convert to `number(Int or Float)` using ParseInt or ParseFloat, like so:

```
 typeof parseFloat(data.input_data['price-row_122'], 10) // "number"
 parseFloat(data.input_data['price-row_122'], 10) // 35.1
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to print object then

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); //this will convert json to string;
```

If you want to access value of field in object then use

```
console.log(data.input_data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `util` library:

```
const util = require("util")

> myObject = {1:2, 3:{5:{6:{7:8}}}}
{ '1': 2, '3': { '5': { '6': [Object] } } }

> util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: true, depth: null})
"{\n  '1': 2,\n  '3': { '5': { '6': { '7': 8 } } }\n}"

> JSON.stringify(myObject)
'{"1":2,"3":{"5":{"6":{"7":8}}}}'
```

original source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729284/8556340

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I'm chiming in because (as Narem briefly mentioned) a few of the printf-like features are available with the `console.log` [formatters](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter). In the case of the question, you can benefit from the string, number or json formatters for your data.

**Examples:**

```
console.log("Quantity %s, Price: %d", data.quantity-row_122, data.price-row_122);
console.log("Quantity and Price Data %j", data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Object

> input_data: Object
>         price-row_122: " 35.1 "
>         quantity-row_122: "1"
>       success: true

Comment: A few words explaining your answer would be helpful