# API getting info from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to fetch simple data from https://picsum.photos/v2/list

```
let data = [];

  const f1_data = await fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list").then((res) =>
    res.json()
  );
  data = f1_data;
  console.log(data);
```

But I can't access data in the array, all I'm getting [object Object].

How, for example, I can access all authors or Theys ID, or any specific info in object?

Comment: Why don't you use the data within another `.then()`, like it is done in these [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples)?

Comment: The OP simply needs to e.g. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array) the `f1_data` / `data` array(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question, you can simply iterate over the array returned by the API like so:

```js
for (const image of f1_data) {
  console.log(image.author)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. You should await the json() function too. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497100/13714320) out for using await and then/catch.

```
let data = [];
const f1_data = await fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list");
const f1_data_json = await f1_data.json();
data = f1_data_json;
data.forEach((photo) => {console.log(photo.author)})
```

Answer (score -1):

You do have access to that data. The only problem is the way you are logging it. You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your object to string.

```js
let data = [];

  const f1_data = await fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list").then((res) =>
    res.json()
  );
  data = f1_data;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Duplicate of [How to print JSON data in console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149462/how-to-print-json-data-in-console-log)