# Getting [object, Object] instead of whole user data. What does that mean?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am getting the [object,Object ] in my server terminal instead of whole user data . I do not know what does that mean... I think I did all perfectly but still unable to get the whole data. I specified of sailjs server.
How to get whole user data instead of [object,Object]?

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Check the provided email address and password, and if they
   * match a real user in the database, sign in to Medool.
   */
  login: function (req, res) {

    // Try to look up user using the provided email address
    User.findOne({
      email: req.param('email')
    }, function foundUser(err, user) {

      if (err)
        return res.negotiate(err);
      if (!user)
        return res.notFound();

      // Compare password attempt from the form params to the encrypted password
      // from the database (`user.password`)
      require('machinepack-passwords').checkPassword({
        passwordAttempt: req.param('password'),
        encryptedPassword: user.encryptedPassword
      }).exec({
        error: function (err) {
          return res.negotiate(err);
        },
        /*
         If the password from the form params doesn't checkout w/ the encrypted
         password from the database...
         */
        incorrect: function () {
          return res.notFound();
        },
        success: function () {

          // Store user id in the user session
          console.log("User form the login check" +user)

          req.session.me = user.helpsterId;
          console.log(req.session.me);

          // All done- let the client know that everything worked.
          return res.ok();
        }
      });
    });

  }

};
```

[Output when lifted server is [object, Object]in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsGo9.png)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-js-console-log-rather-than-object

Comment: That's what you get when you concatenate a string and an object, try doing `console.log("User form the login check", user)` instead to see the object

Comment: A `toString` called on javascript object evaluates to `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Thanks a lot adeneo ur genuine .... :D@adeneo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it,

```
console.log(user);
console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
console.log("User form the login check" +user);
```

and write the result for us.

Comment: { helpsterId: 1,
  firstname: 'Bill',
  lastname: 'Gates',
  mobile: 9560644561,
  email: 'bill@gates.com',
  encryptedPassword: '$2a$10$gezlHKlHZniBugT4MhXlDeWm1yR6S656eMIssTxssGcoh4A/HbZKu',
  gender: 'male',
  online: true,
  admin: true,
  dob: '2012-03-20T18:30:00.000Z',
}

Comment: User form the login check[object Object]

Comment: `console.log("User form the login check" +user.firstname);`