# iterating over JSON object in ejs partial

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I am trying to loop over each entry in "default", in my JSON file below, within an EJS partial.

```
{
    "default": {
        "1": {
            "id": "alertmessages",
            "title": "Your Messages",
            "subtitle": "Tasks waiting for your attention",
            "image": "alert.png",
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "uploadr",
            "title": "Upload",
            "subtitle": "Upload",
            "image": "baskets.png",
        },
        etc............
    }
}
```

I am reading this JSON file into my node.js, parsing it and making it available for my dashboard view. as below

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./app/routes/dashboard/buttons.json', 'utf8'));

var content = {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    user: req.user,
    buttonsdata: jsondata
};
res.render('dashboard', content);
```

My dashboard view, includes an ejs partial in which I am trying to loop over all the objects contained within default (this number may vary). I want to do this without Jquery. But having trouble getting any of the suggestions working that I have found on other threads.

```
console.log("<%= buttonsdata.default.[1].id %>")
```

gives me what I would expect, however if i try and console log **buttons.length**, which is used in loop examples I have seen, it just comes up blank.
also how can I console log the entire contents of the object to see its structure?
thirdly - this object, in this manner as I can tell is available through ejs, however not to core javascript and i can only access it using the ejs <% %> tags. is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your json contains only objects, it doesn't have any arrays in it, so you  won't be able to use `buttonsdata.length`
2. *Displaying the whole object* - display the object from within your controller, not your template. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729284/459233) to see how
3. *this object is available through ejs* - yes, that's a correct understanding - I assume that by *core javascript* you mean the javascript that's executed in the browser. The whole ejs template is processed on the backend.

Comment: thanks. 1. will restructure the JSON    2. It only outputs [Object Object] , does that give any clues to where I went wrong? 3. thats right.

Comment: you are a star. That solved it, just needed to make it an array. making more sense now. kind regards

Comment: Cool. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const buttonsdata = {
  "default": {
    "1": {
      "id": "alertmessages",
      "title": "Your Messages",
      "subtitle": "Tasks waiting for your attention",
      "image": "alert.png",
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "uploadr",
      "title": "Upload",
      "subtitle": "Upload",
      "image": "baskets.png",
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(buttonsdata.default).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(buttonsdata.default[key].id);
});
```

Now, according to your code, in the view should work like this:

```
<ul>
<% Object.keys(buttonsdata.default).forEach(function(key) { %> 
    <li><%= buttonsdata.default[key].id %></li>
<% }) %>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it.  Some might recommend `for ... in` but `for ... in` is hella dangerous.