# console.log formatting for dates and objects

Tags: javascript

How can we format a `value` into a string to be consistent with how `console.log(value)` does it?

I need to append extra details to each value I am printing, without breaking the default formatting provided by `console.log`. It is easy for simple values, but for such types as `Date` and `Object` it is more complicated.

Is there a way I can make it consistent with `console.log`? In other words, how to format a `value` to be the same string as we get from `console.log(value)`?

---

I'm trying to implement a simple library [manakin](https://github.com/vitaly-t/manakin). Here's its complete source code:

```
'use strict';

(function () {

    var error = console.error, warn = console.warn;

    console.error = function () {
        var a = arguments;
        error.apply(this, Object.keys(a).map(function (key) {
            return "\u001b[31m" + a[key] + "\u001b[0m";
        }));
    };

    console.warn = function () {
        var a = arguments;
        warn.apply(this, Object.keys(a).map(function (key) {
            return "\u001b[33m" + a[key] + "\u001b[0m";
        }));
    };

})();
```

The problem I am having is that for types `Date` and `Object` the output is different:

```
// without manakin:
console.warn({value: 1});
//=> { value: 1 }

// with manakin:
console.warn({value: 1});
//=> [object Object]
```

And I want to make it consistent.

Comment: can you show an example output?

Comment: @JordanHendrix I have added the complete code ;)

Comment: Simply put; if `console.log` is like a `printf`, then OP wants a `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you modify the code in warn to be:

```
console.warn = function () {
    var a = arguments;
    warn.apply(this, Object.keys(a).map(function (key) {
      if (a[key] instanceof Date) {
        return "\u001b[33m" + a[key].toString() + "\u001b[0m";
      }
      return "\u001b[33m" + JSON.stringify(a[key]) + "\u001b[0m";
    }));
};
```

you have what you're looking for. I tested it out by just pasting the new code in the console and logging the examples you have, hope that works for you!

Comment: I thought this approach too, but for dates, `JSON.stringify` returns them in RFC3339 format, while `console.log` prints them in what seems to be RFC1123. Maybe checking for `a[key] instanceof Date` and, if true, use `a[key].toString()` instead.

Comment: But the output from `JSON.stringify` is still very different from `console.log` formatting.

Comment: I think I will make it for Node.js only, and then use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-js-console-log-rather-than-object. Because otherwise there seems to be no way to provide consistent formatting.

Comment: In the end I got it all working everywhere - see the update ;)