# Node.js - console.log does not show items in array but instead shows [Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, console.log

I have a problem with logging out the contents of an array inside an object. The actual object looks like this

```
   var stuff = { accepted: [ 'item1', 'item2' ],
         rejected: [],
         response: 'Foo',
         envelope: { from: 'The sender', to: ['new item1', 'new item2'] },
         messageId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' } }
```

The `console.log` shows the items of the first array fine but the second array is being output as `[Object]`.

```
 { accepted: [ 'item1', 'item2' ],
             rejected: [],
             response: 'Foo',
             envelope: { from: 'The sender', to: [Object] },
             messageId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' } }
```

What is happening here and how can I get the items of the second array to show when I `console.log`. Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I forgot to add that I am working exclusively in Node.js so it's a server side log that needs to display the object exactly as it's received from a callback with a straight `console.log`, ie. no further stringify-ing.

I also just tried creating another random object with a similar structure like this.

```
 var objText = {
      fun: {
        stuff: 'Some stuff',
        list: ['this', 'it', 'takes']
      }
    };
```

The `console.log` for the above is:

```
{ fun: { stuff: 'Some stuff', list: [ 'this', 'it', 'takes' ] } }
```

This appears to be the same structure to me and yet the `console.log` works fine so it seems to be perfectly possible in Node to log arrays content even when it's embedded inside and an object inside an outer object.

Comment: Which browser/env are you using? In Safari 10.1.1 it displays fine.

Comment: For example, nodejs logs it that way

Answer (score 9):

It looks like this is an old topic, anyway

I've faced the same issue, embedded array printed as `[Array]`.

It is because of console.log in the node.js uses `util.inspect` for print, the default depth is 2.
So, to print something which is deeper than 2 followings can be used:

```
const util = require('util')
console.log(util.inspect(errors, true, 10))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: 1. `console.log` does use `util.inspect` with depth = 2 (hence the problem of OP), and 2. using the suggested solution does remedy the issue. Also, if you add last parameter to `util.inspect` and pass `true`, `console.log` will behave the same as before (e.g. show colours as well). Depth (here 10) can be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

This is the default way for some browser and implementations of showing too complex or deep objects/arrays with console.log. An alternative is to use JSON.stringify with console.log:

```js
var stuff = {
  accepted: ['item1', 'item2'],
  rejected: [],
  response: 'Foo',
  envelope: {
    from: 'The sender',
    to: ['new item1', 'new item2']
  },
  messageId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(stuff, null, 4));
```

EDIT:

Another alternative is to use `console.dir` in case you have a too complex or recursive object, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534731/6051261

Answer (score 4):

Try it with: `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))`

Answer (score 0):

If you like Chrome devtools, that folds your json objects and let you observe a lot of things, you can use the `--inspect` flag:

```
node --inspect index.js
```

The console will then give you an URL and you just have to copy paste in Google Chrome to enjoy Google Chrome console.

[More information on this link](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I'm on Node 0.12 and can't upgrade at the moment.