# Why is the JSON output different from the actual output as rendered in the browser?

Tags: node.js, api, google-maps, express, google-maps-api-3

So I have to make an API call to Google directions API, using this code and trying to store the response in "lat" variable.

```
app.post("/from", function(req,res) {
      from = req.body.from;
      to = req.body.to;
      const url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+ from + "&destination=" + to + "&key=AIzaSyDYRICW4Bm4donS0-9LCp_h0nlsyWvEuGY";
      console.log(from,to);
      https.get(url, function(response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        var buffers = []
      response
        .on('data', function(data) {
          buffers.push(data)
        })
        .on('end', function() {

          lat = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString());
```

But when i try to log that response I am getting this  using console.log(lat) which is truncated like inside routes:[Array].

```
{
      geocoded_waypoints: [
        {
          geocoder_status: 'OK',
          place_id: 'ChIJ5zr8Xtk9rjsRrZrdrpG3Dck',
          types: [Array]
        },
        {
          geocoder_status: 'OK',
          place_id: 'ChIJxfW4DPM9rjsRKsNTG-5p_QQ',
          types: [Array]
        }
      ],
      routes: [
        {
          bounds: [Object],
          copyrights: 'Map data ©2020',
          legs: [Array],
          overview_polyline: [Object],
          summary: '1st Cross Rd/Siddhaiah Puranik Rd and Dr MC Modi Hospital Rd',
          warnings: [],
          waypoint_order: []
        }
      ],
      status: 'OK'
    }
```

However, the same response inside the browser is something different and much useful, response from browser is as follows

```
{
    "geocoded_waypoints": [
    {
    "geocoder_status": "OK",
    "place_id": "ChIJa147K9HX3IAR-lwiGIQv9i4",
    "types": [
    "amusement_park",
    "establishment",
    "point_of_interest",
    "tourist_attraction"
    ]
    },
    {
    "geocoder_status": "OK",
    "place_id": "ChIJzzgyJU--woARcZqceSdQ3dM",
    "types": [
    "amusement_park",
    "establishment",
    "point_of_interest",
    "tourist_attraction"
    ]
    }
    ],
    "routes": [
    {
    "bounds": {
    "northeast": {
    "lat": 34.1358593,
    "lng": -117.922066
    },
    "southwest": {
    "lat": 33.81558589999999,
    "lng": -118.3517014
    }
    },
    "copyrights": "Map data ©2020",
    "legs": [
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "35.1 mi",
    "value": 56511
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "51 mins",
    "value": 3031
    },
    "end_address": "100 Universal City Plaza, Universal City, CA 91608, USA",
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.1358593,
    "lng": -118.3511633
    },
    "start_address": "1313 Disneyland Dr, Anaheim, CA 92802, USA",
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8160897,
    "lng": -117.9225226
    },
    "steps": [
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "10 ft",
    "value": 3
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 0
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.8160679,
    "lng": -117.9225314
    },
    "html_instructions": "Head <b>southwest</b>",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "qukmEvvvnUB@"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8160897,
    "lng": -117.9225226
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "397 ft",
    "value": 121
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 11
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.8155824,
    "lng": -117.9235917
    },
    "html_instructions": "Keep <b>right</b>",
    "maneuver": "keep-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "mukmExvvnUZPLJLLBBFJFLHPBPBL@N?L?J@l@"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8160679,
    "lng": -117.9225314
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "417 ft",
    "value": 127
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 57
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.816278,
    "lng": -117.9242395
    },
    "html_instructions": "Slight <b>right</b> toward <b>Southwest Pl</b>/<wbr/><b>West Pl</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Restricted usage road</div>",
    "maneuver": "turn-slight-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "krkmEl}vnUKTAFAF?D?x@?F?DABABCBC?C@E?eB?"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8155824,
    "lng": -117.9235917
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "0.1 mi",
    "value": 164
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 74
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.817613,
    "lng": -117.924097
    },
    "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Southwest Pl</b>/<wbr/><b>West Pl</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Partial restricted usage road</div>",
    "maneuver": "turn-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "wvkmEnawnUEe@O?[BI?C?MEY?c@@E?G?EBKDk@?Q?_@?"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.816278,
    "lng": -117.9242395
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "243 ft",
    "value": 74
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 27
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.8179964,
    "lng": -117.9235637
    },
    "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> toward <b>W Ball Rd</b>",
    "maneuver": "turn-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "a_lmEr`wnU?S?O?O?AA?AA?AMKGGCCKGMGECCACAGA"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.817613,
    "lng": -117.924097
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "374 ft",
    "value": 114
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 48
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.8179846,
    "lng": -117.9223305
    },
    "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>W Ball Rd</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Pass by Staybridge Suites Anaheim at the Park (on the right)</div>",
    "maneuver": "turn-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "oalmEf}vnU?k@@iA@_C"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8179964,
    "lng": -117.9235637
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "0.2 mi",
    "value": 352
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 69
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.8207878,
    "lng": -117.9230963
    },
    "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Disneyland Dr</b>",
    "maneuver": "turn-left",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "kalmEpuvnUAs@_@Bk@HA?UFKBa@JuCp@{@T_@LYLKJUJc@LEBeAX"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8179846,
    "lng": -117.9223305
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "22.3 mi",
    "value": 35884
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "28 mins",
    "value": 1673
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.0256221,
    "lng": -118.2059515
    },
    "html_instructions": "Slight <b>right</b> to merge onto <b>I-5 N</b> toward <b>Los Angeles</b>",
    "maneuver": "ramp-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "}rlmEjzvnUi@MICEASIcA]{@[C?SGSGMEMEC?KCSAEAMAO?E?]@C?E@E?MBE@I@IBKBA@UJE@EBIDGDKF}ArAs@l@y@r@y@r@}@v@WTs@l@qAjA_@\]p@}ApAg@b@iAdA}BbCSTYXw@z@[ZyB`CsAxAOP[^cBlBw@x@qBtB}@~@_AbA{@|@s@x@KLEBEDSPGF_BhCa@r@Wh@Wf@Sf@c@jAOb@K^ITW`AMd@_@xAWnAU`Bm@jEi@`Eu@hFOv@GXWlAMh@e@|AM`@M^KX{@vBuAzCSd@aGrMwDvISd@aEjJgB|DoApCyCzGuBxEy@lBu@~AWl@Q^Uf@_@t@a@r@a@r@A@Yd@y@zA}@|AQZYd@[h@U`@QZ[l@c@|@_@v@{@rBUn@s@hB_BjE_BtDSd@aCbGSb@k@zAu@hB[t@aChGQf@{CjHyAjDiAhCoAxCmDhIkApCkAdCEFoA|B_@j@Yf@gA~Aa@l@g@p@W^a@j@GHgAtAu@dAiCpDY\aB|Be@z@?@A@IPKRA@?@GJSd@_@~@Qh@Qh@WdAADAFGZYrA[xAId@GREVSbAU~@k@vB[lACF_AzE?@YlAMl@ADWbAOn@}@hCQh@k@~AcB~DYp@Wh@qAjCc@x@QZgBzC_BpC[f@c@t@U^KPqB`ESb@ABQ^g@fASb@Sf@c@`AoAtCe@fAaBtDg@hAy@jBsAbD}@nBOZKV]v@oArCSb@Q`@?@Sb@aBpDi@hAy@lBKVsAnCABGHGNINEJCJGJGRc@`A[t@c@`AoAlCmBjEMZ]t@_@z@w@bBe@|@c@r@OTOTA@SZCBc@r@a@h@g@n@e@j@Y^QRi@l@_@b@MPA?_@f@GFw@`AiBjCe@r@S^a@t@Ub@g@fACD_@x@CDMXm@tAqAxCiBbEg@lAcAzBYl@Wn@GJIRaBxDsBvEa@~@CFSb@g@hAGLITmApCg@fAMZ_ArB{@lBSb@Yp@}@rBcAzBGN_@x@Qb@w@fBkBdEqA|CiAtB_BxCaAfBuAhCS`@s@xAO\_@z@w@rBa@fAIVq@xAcA|BGLgBfDYh@GJGLMVGNsA`Dc@bASj@y@rBa@~@aA|B[x@e@hA]z@a@bAsAhD?@uCbHSd@O`@g@jAABm@vAsA`DmB`FIPwC~GiF|Ky@`BGJmBvD{AzCqDjHiBnDkCpFiEbJ{@hBmCzFkAhCcArCi@jAQd@g@fAGLKTcBtDaAhBmAzBa@t@a@t@mAlBmAlBaB~BW\qAdBi@p@m@r@EDgBnBaChCmChCEBwBpBeBfBeAdAKLmBlBgBbBsAnAeAdAQVi@n@kA~A{@dA_@h@e@z@Yf@[l@IN[n@MVSb@q@zAw@|AIPm@vAq@|A[r@Sb@Yn@MVu@pAq@hAg@p@gBnCcBzB_ApA{D`EkAbAeAx@QJYVYVgDzBw@f@w@d@{CnBmAx@IDwA~@OJQJEBQJCB]NqD|BiBhAyClB}@l@WN}H|E_@T{A~@}BtA]T{D`C}@h@}BrAwA|@{BvAg@Xg@Ze@XcBlAwCpB{@l@kD`CgA|@_@ReCxAoG`EcAn@SLm@^wAz@a@Ve@ZiEdCq@`@_@R?@wBlAGBoBjA}BrAKFGDu@b@k@Xi@XWNcB`Aa@VoDvBwCbBcAn@}@h@yBlA_@Re@V[RMF_@Ru@b@GDm@\yAz@SJc@VeAn@q@`@}A|@sBjA}@h@]TcDjBkAp@cAl@ID}@h@wCdB_@T_@T_Ap@y@n@g@b@i@f@_@^a@`@UXm@r@_@b@a@j@QVwAvBk@|@A@W^cA~AeA`B{BhDeA~A_@l@iAfB}@rAuCnEo@`Ao@bAMPSZCBuAvByBhDgA`BW^_AxAiIhMW^uBbDW^gAdBSXSZg@n@MPEDe@j@_@^[\kAdAe@\UNOLs@d@CB}@j@sAr@e@TC@MD[Lq@Vs@R_B`@iE|@WFqDr@sAZs@NWDcB^ODc@HcB\C@]HaAP}A\c@Jg@JgAZi@Nu@XiAd@gAh@eAl@MHKFe@TGDSL{@h@i@^s@j@cAr@}B~A[PeAr@SNyB|A_@\cAz@qAnAoApA_A|@{A|AYX_A~@}@|@eAbAs@t@uBtBoBpBmAlA{AzAm@j@YZ]\kAhAeAhAg@f@KLOPs@|@a@n@QXq@fA{@vAy@tA]l@[b@w@pA[b@a@d@CBYZ[\w@v@YT?@CBKJA?ON]\s@r@wAxAmAlA}@x@y@v@A@wErEmJzIiJ|IONoBjB_@Zc@^EB]Zo@n@q@l@MNc@\o@d@m@`@y@d@IDULk@Zq@Xq@Zq@^ID_@TC@k@\cAt@}@t@CBoBjByCpCkB`B}AzA_CvB}AvAu@r@cA`AoAtAgEhFgBvBY\aCtCwAbBa@r@[d@i@|@S`@Ud@g@bAYj@o@fASZQVcAnAeAnAi@h@UTs@l@uBhBw@r@_@\MJYVg@f@g@j@e@p@MPMTW^k@dAy@lBeAxCQ`@GPYx@Qd@KZCH}@jCy@|BQd@iCpHeAzCcA|CYfAW~A}@nECRk@~B]`AYp@KVg@dAq@pAOXIPA@A@Ud@MXABEJGNCFAB[t@ADADi@~ASl@EPITWt@cAbDaAnCkCrHa@hAA@GNq@lBe@vAYbAK`@ABU~@CLMt@m@vDOrAEh@Eh@GjAGfBAtBAL@|J@xM@lB?nE?rEAbD?@Ct@EhAA`@C`@It@MrAE^Ih@Mz@QfAKh@Mf@Qt@Of@W|@Sp@wBpGiAfD{@jCQf@Od@q@pBOf@eBdFAFaB|EaBfF}AvEm@xAK`@[lAWfAELGZK^"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 33.8207878,
    "lng": -117.9230963
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "11.7 mi",
    "value": 18811
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "17 mins",
    "value": 1002
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.1294658,
    "lng": -118.3475583
    },
    "html_instructions": "Keep <b>left</b> at the fork to continue on <b>US-101 N</b>, follow signs for <b>Los Angeles N</b>/<wbr/><b>Civic Center</b>",
    "maneuver": "fork-left",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "cstnEdbnpU@d@?@?@?@CJELg@xBW`AMf@Od@Ut@cArCmAnDKXKVsA~D_C|GwAhEGPKXa@hA[~@aApCe@vAi@zACDWn@a@hAUn@w@hBOZS`@[p@INCFGJOVOX]j@]h@MTg@r@W\UZe@j@KLGDABC@C@SHiAhAA?EDw@x@[Zs@h@m@`@]TKDQLQF[NEBSJE@KDMDiAXC@]JWDg@FOB]Dy@DU?_@@u@As@EoBWy@Gu@Ek@?MAQ?_@@[BmAFy@Fa@@U@a@?W?a@Aa@CC?]C]Cm@KWCKCmASyC]}CU]Ak@Ae@?wA@iB@oC@k@?}AFi@@aAHS@k@Di@Hm@Fm@JyAXi@L_Bb@C@_A\c@PsAh@UHeAh@_@L]Nc@Pc@Pe@R}@\{An@WNUNA?ML_@XMNIJQRQVGJABIJQ^[z@A??BEJOd@CLAHCJAHCP?HCNAPARAb@Er@?HAF?DAJ?DADG^AJC^AFATCJ?DAJOnAU~BKhAEZC`@CNMrAKpAQzBMtAOzBCRGbAAJK|ACRAT?TCv@ARCVEZIdAGbA?BCZEbACj@CdAAz@Bv@@J@PDbA@d@@P?R?N?PALALARCPCPERCNGZG\I^GPCJUl@Wn@CHCDIPOZOVa@v@_@n@MVS\QZGLYh@e@z@GJGJIPKPGJmA|Bk@fA_@p@k@dAS`@o@jA]n@QZ]n@_@p@KNs@lAMRKP]h@w@pAk@v@W\CBSZEBSXkAzAST_@`@i@h@g@d@g@b@URUPUPo@h@gA|@gA|@k@d@eBvAEBi@b@ED]XEBUPWTED_@ZYVSRQNY\QTY^UZW^g@x@]h@GHq@dASXW`@[`@S\e@p@w@lAINe@p@U`@m@|@A@cA~Aa@p@OXg@`AMXYl@Q`@O\Wr@O^GPGR[~@ELMd@?@K\_@tA?B[nAi@tB[nAiAnE_@xAWdAQp@e@lBCD[nAK`@ADe@jBMf@Mf@Mf@YhAQj@Oh@q@vBi@|Ai@zAc@nAa@nAADc@jA]fAABQd@a@jACL[~@M\c@tA]hAa@pAABCHCJIViApDc@jAGPIRu@jBg@lAc@fAM^K\Od@m@nBa@|AYdAKb@Mj@ETu@vDa@zB]~Au@~Dq@rDS|@Y|ACHAJMn@I`@I`@If@YjB]`CO`A?@Kr@?DCP_@nCm@~DQpAAJQdACTETc@fDMjAShBKlACPGh@Ij@Ij@Mx@[hBId@Ot@c@hBKf@Wz@c@lAKZUj@CDk@pAYr@CDg@dAMZEJ_AvBeAhCO^}@dC}@`Cm@dBQd@Up@wB~FSh@g@rAEHSb@_@x@?Ba@t@KRSb@Wd@CD]n@c@x@o@bAe@t@c@t@_@l@ILILABMTKPMPqBfD{AbCu@hAOVmAjBQTILg@l@g@n@i@f@k@j@k@d@e@^m@b@_@V_@VC@ABSPQHUL{Av@iExB_@R}@d@[NCBq@\k@XUN[P]To@d@URc@`@g@h@WVe@l@QTOVMR_@l@i@`AGJAB[l@q@lA_AdB_@r@}@`Bc@v@_A|As@hAKNMPg@n@c@h@QPEF_@`@_@^KHYXYTq@j@YPaAt@eAj@IFq@\kB|@oHrDwAr@a@Pe@Re@Vs@\s@b@[R_@X[VSRSR[Zc@h@UXQTU^i@~@i@hA_@~@Y`Ak@|BG\Mv@E`@E\Gx@A@?RCXC|@A^?h@?^?TA^Av@?F?Z?~@Cn@?@A`@Cb@G|@ALCRE\G\CRABEVEPAHK`@K`@Oj@i@xAQ^Wj@Wh@]l@u@vAu@vAOZEFU`@]p@Uf@s@vAqDnHu@zAkAzBm@lAQXkA`Cg@|@[n@[j@KL[f@W\EFY^[^c@b@GFCD]XMJ_@\SP]XKF]Tg@TMHMDMFUHMBIBE@k@NC@[FSFYFIB_@H]HgBb@yD|@m@T?@oDr@iB^sATw@NQBKBiANaB^gAVc@Pa@Nw@Xk@VaAb@]Na@ToAt@qBlAqAfA_Av@kAjAgBlBYXCFEDEFCB?@KLGFKJq@x@a@h@i@n@QXSVSVcAlAY^Y\[^UXWZc@f@g@f@ONg@b@KHMJk@^A@}@j@eB`AWL[RYRWPQNQLa@\ONQPi@h@iBjBEFMJWVMNYVUV_@^uAvAo@p@"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 34.0256221,
    "lng": -118.2059515
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "0.1 mi",
    "value": 180
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 10
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.1307998,
    "lng": -118.3485738
    },
    "html_instructions": "Take exit <b>11B</b> toward <b>Universal Studios Blvd</b>",
    "maneuver": "ramp-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "e|hoEfwiqUAACAA?A?C?E?A@C@MHURYXA?IHa@^WV[VKJEDGFIFIFKHCBA?A?A@A?A?C?CA"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 34.1294658,
    "lng": -118.3475583
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "0.3 mi",
    "value": 447
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 32
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.1338819,
    "lng": -118.3515888
    },
    "html_instructions": "Merge onto <b>W.C. Fields Dr</b>",
    "maneuver": "merge",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "odioEp}iqUMLSLYNEBYNe@Xk@`@]V]VSJMH]TEBKJIHMLKLSVU\S\CDQZGLKNGLGFCFEDCBCBCBC@EDEBEBC@EDCBEBEBCB?@CBC@CBEFCBCDEDEFINUd@"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 34.1307998,
    "lng": -118.3485738
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    },
    {
    "distance": {
    "text": "0.1 mi",
    "value": 234
    },
    "duration": {
    "text": "1 min",
    "value": 28
    },
    "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.1358593,
    "lng": -118.3511633
    },
    "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Universal Studios Blvd</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the right</div>",
    "maneuver": "turn-right",
    "polyline": {
    "points": "wwioElpjqUQNA@A@A?A@C?C?A?A?A?C?CAA?CAAAA??AA?CAEAC?A?A?A?A?A?A?OQCAAAECUMGCGCECGCGCICICICGAECKACAGAIAGAGAG?IAQAWAIAI?K?I@O@IA"
    },
    "start_location": {
    "lat": 34.1338819,
    "lng": -118.3515888
    },
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
    }
    ],
    "traffic_speed_entry": [],
    "via_waypoint": []
    }
    ],
    "overview_polyline": {
    "points": "qukmEvvvnUz@l@\n@H|@KvAI`BsB@Ee@O?e@BoAC_@H}@?_@??S?_@?ACCe@_@[OGm@BiEAs@_@Bm@HyEhAaC|@eCv@eF_BgB]wAHmAb@oJdIeCxB}@nAmI~H{JtKgOfPg@b@qDnGsAvDoAvEeC~PeBhKoAhEqDrIwa@b_AyCzGyBdEqFnJqB~DeFxMiOh_@gVdk@oCxEiD~EgDpEkHhKa@x@wAxDc@nBcDzNaDxNkCbIgFfL_JrOmG~M{MxZkN~ZgC`GiFjLaDpGgDzEkDbEiE|FqBlDgIzQoRlc@aIrQuEjK{CrGaD`GmDbHcCnG}GhNaUnj@kDhIwBrFaK|TkG`MqRp`@iEdJoC|GkBfE_GpL_FfIuFtH}GrHySlSuE|EmEjGgFjKwFxLeHfK{FrGqC|BmFvDyIvF}D`Cuu@be@ySvN{ThNe\fRo]fSmR~KoNrIkDzCeCrC{I|Mu^xj@gSxZyAbBmC`C}AfA{DvBoC~@sNzC_L`CaFdAoEpAsHxDqM~IyCzBuCjCeGfGgShS{H`IyCnEoD~FyB~CgCfCkElEom@tk@{DjC}BhAmCvAqDjCkVbUsCvCoH`JuGjIuF~JeE`FwF`FgA`AcCvCkChFyBfG{JhY}AdFuAnHo@rCw@rBuBhEMTy@jBcMp^}BjH[pAqAjJWrI@zo@m@nJu@vEgAbEuJ~YkHrTsD`Lq@pC@h@}BzI}Mn`@wF~O}DjJqDzFoAzA]PiChC{C|BwBbAgFdAeDDsGk@qHTsEK_Dg@aKw@wJDuFRwCXqDr@gEtAoEjBsItDkBnBiAfCc@~Bg@bHyCp]a@|Ge@zKPtFWhCa@jBu@rBqChFoLrTgEjHyF`IoFbFgKpIeDrCkEbG_NzSaDnHcB`GkK~a@sFhQ_DlJwChJ_CfHkCtGmDfMqGx\wE~ZuBlP_BjLwAbGiAzCkGzNmJnWcDlHcOxVeDbFcCrCqFjE{MdHwBjA_C`BiCpCoAnB_HhMcDnFkB|BqE`EcEfCuOvHsDlBkBxAiBrB{B~Dy@`Cs@zCa@pDKlFInGe@vEYtAwAfEeFxJ{M`XkDzGeAzAqDtD{AhAqAl@sCt@qLxCoRpDeErAmD`BaEbCqC~BqEzEaBnB}FnHmB|BkBdBsG|DcElDsFvFkCdCM?qBdB_ChB_IdFmDdFiA~@gA~ASBe@KiB_AcAU_BKo@@"
    },
    "summary": "I-5 N and US-101 N",
    "warnings": [],
    "waypoint_order": []
    }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Node.js - console.log does not show items in array but instead shows \[Object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444601/node-js-console-log-does-not-show-items-in-array-but-instead-shows-object)