# jQuery scraping elements from the DOM (simple, thoroughly explained Q!)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping

I'm struggling to wrap my head around what is actually returned when we scrape a parent element with JS/jQuery. Through my learning, I have found that a good way to approach scraping an item on the page with multiple properties that we want scrape into unique arrays *(let's say Book Title, Book Price, Inventory Status)*, would be to locate the parent element, convert that an array, then `.map()` through it to extract each element that we want.

For a simple example, all of the data I need is located in the `product_pod` class in the code below.

```
<article class="product_pod">
<div class="image_container">...</div>
<p class="star-rating Five">...</p>
<h3>
  <a href="catalogue/libertarianism_for_beginners_999/index.html" title="Libertarianism for Beginners">Libertarianism for Beginners</a>
</h3>
<div class="product_price">
  <p class="price_color">$53.74</p>
  <p class="instock">In Stock</p>
</div>
</article>
```

So I understand that I need to iterate through the `product_pod` array. I've followed other programmer's leads to come up with this:

```
const container = $('.product_pod').toArray();
let mapper = container.map(elem => {
        const activate = $(elem);
        const title = activate.find('a').map((i, x) => $(x).attr('title'));
        const price = activate.find('.price_color').text();
        const inventory = activate.find('.instock').text().trim();
        return({title,price,inventory});
    })
```

Or something like that.

What I'm asking is that when I `console.log(container)`, I get this absolutely unreadable object returned (img below), where *Book Title, Book Price, Inventory Status* are nowhere to be found.

Why does it do this? How can I read this? And how can I set up a map function with all of these unnamed `[Object], [Array]` fields, when I have no idea how to iterate through the gibberish?

Thank you guys and gals.

[image]

Updated log:
[image]

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444601/node-js-console-log-does-not-show-items-in-array-but-instead-shows-object) to know why console.log displays "bullshit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a call to `get()` to retrieve the array generated by `map()` stored within the resulting jQuery object. It's that jQuery object which you're seeing logged to the console.

```
const $container = $('.product_pod');
let mapper = $container.map(elem => {
  const $activate = $(elem);
  const title = $activate.find('a').map((i, x) => $(x).('title')).get();
  const price = $activate.find('.price_color').text();
  const inventory = $activate.find('.instock').text().trim();
  return({ title, price, inventory });
}).get();
```

Note that I made a couple of tweaks in the above code. Firstly, `toArray()` isn't required as `map()` will iterate through Elements within a jQuery object already.
Secondly you should look to use `prop()` over `attr()` where possible.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. However, this does not exactly solve my issue. Perhaps I should note that I'm using Cheerio?

Comment: I have included an updated screenshot of my console, including the unintelligible objects its returning. I would love to know more about the .get() method, in the context of manipulating arrays. I was excited for that solution but no dice yet.

Comment: Ah, my bad! I missed a `get()` call on the inner `map()` reference. I updated the answer for you