# After parsing a Nodejs response. The JSON response results array is outputing as just object. How do I get to to display the objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

Here I call the module. Then ask for the response. then I use `JSON.parse` the body of the response but the output looks like this.

```
{ response:
   { status: 'ok',
     userTier: 'developer',
     total: 240,
     startIndex: 1,
     pageSize: 1,
     currentPage: 1,
     pages: 240,
     orderBy: 'newest',
     results: [ [Object] ] } }
```

I want to be able to see the Objects

```
    {
    "response": {
        "status": "ok",
        "userTier": "developer",
        "total": 240,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "pageSize": 1,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "pages": 240,
        "orderBy": "newest",
        "results": [{
            "id": "sustainable-business/2017/jun/13/battery-storage-and-rooftop-solar-could-mean-new-life-post-grid-for-consumers",
            "type": "article",
            "sectionId": "sustainable-business",
            "sectionName": "Guardian Sustainable Business",
            "webPublicationDate": "2017-06-12T23:51:00Z",
            "webTitle": "Battery storage and rooftop solar could mean new life post-grid for consumers",
            "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/2017/jun/13/battery-storage-and-rooftop-solar-could-mean-new-life-post-grid-for-consumers",
            "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/sustainable-business/2017/jun/13/battery-storage-and-rooftop-solar-could-mean-new-life-post-grid-for-consumers",
            "isHosted": false
        }]
    }
}
```

this is the code

```js
function prettyJSON(data) {
 return JSON.stringify(data,null,"   ");
}


api.custom.search({fromDate:"2017-06-12", 
     toDate:"2017-06-12", 
     orderBy:"newest",
     //showFields:"all",
     pageSize: 2})
 .then(function(response){
  var reqBody = response.body.toString(); 
  reqBody = JSON.parse(reqBody); 
  console.log(reqBody); 
   
 })
 
  .catch(function(err){
  console.log(err); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a console log will not output nested objects so your response is probably fine you just cannot see it in your console.

If you want to inspect it you can either use a debugger and inspect your variable there or use `util.inspect()`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729284/8069575) answer

Edit: The console in Chrome will show the nested objects but node's console does not extend objects by default - thanks to Jeremy Thille for his comment

Comment: It would work in Chrome's console, but indeed, in Node, the console does not extend objects natively.