# Javascript: issue with inheritance test (JS Definitive Guide book supplied code issue)

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I'm new to Javascript. Usually write Python/PHP. Currently reading through ***JavaScript: The Definitive Guide: Activate Your Web Pages (Definitive Guides)***.

Part of the example code used I'm trying to figure out why it won't work, and the detailed explanation why too if possible, is below over properties getter/setters and inheritance.

The function I'm using:

```
function inherit(p) {
     if (p == null) throw TypeError(); 
     if (Object.create) return Object.create(p); 
     var t = typeof p; 
     if (t !== "object" && t !== "function") throw TypeError();
     function f() {}; 
     f.prototype = p; 
     return new f();
}

var p = {
    x: 1.0,
    y: 1.0,
    get r() { 
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y); 
    },
    set r(newvalue) {
        var oldvalue = Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
        var ratio = newvalue/oldvalue;
        this.x *= ratio;
        this.y *= ratio;
    },
        get theta() { return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x); }
};
```

When I run a test. I can't see anything being inherited.

```
> var q = inherit(p)
undefined
> q
{}
> p
{ x: 1, y: 1, r: [Getter/Setter], theta: [Getter] }
```

Why is this? I am currently using `node v6.11.3` on Mac to run this.

Update:

Discovered how to show all values in an Object. Setting `enumerable:True` to an object will auto-display all values. What I was trying to figure out how to do. For any who also use `Node.js`.

Comment: The code works as it should. You are not looking at the full results properly. If you log `q`, you will see all the inherited properties. The `{}` that you are seeing is just the way the console tells you that an object was returned from `inherit(p)`. Add `console.log(inherit(p))` to the bottom of your code and run it. Also, see this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpLu0rkh/3/)**

Comment: Yep. Or run the whole thing in your browser console for easy clicky click click.

Comment: Did not realize I could use the console in Chrome/FF like this with JS snippets of code. Out of curiosity, is there any easy way to get this info in terminal while using `node`? I tried `console.log(inherit(p))` and still gives `{}`. `iPython` I could use 'who' to view all variables and quick look at their variables.

Comment: Use `util.inspect()` as discussed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)**

Comment: This is great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(q))` you should see the inherited properties from `p`. If you check equality with `Object.getPrototypeOf()`, the prototype of `q` should be equal to `p`.

Comment: This should be a comment as there was no problem in the first place.

Comment: Disagree. The problem is(was) that he couldn't see the full output by simply typing `q` into the console. This solves the problem.

Comment: @Will This kind of issue is not code related. The problem has nothing to do with the code presented. As such, it is a question that should be closed here on SO (and I have marked it as such). These kinds of questions should only have comments, not answers.

Comment: @JusMalcolm I noticed I can set `enumerate:true` on an object (`Object.defineProperty()`) and this will automatically show the values (using node.js in terminal, Chrome js console). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use strange class definition and instance like `inherit` function is considered a bad practice, consider use js class ES6 definition, if you can, or function object definition or prototype if you have to use ES5.

Here how to use ES6 class definition

```
class p {

    constructor() {
        this.x = 1.0;
        this.y = 1.0;
    }    

    get r() { 
        return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y); 
    }

    set r(newvalue) {
        var oldvalue = Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
        var ratio = newvalue/oldvalue;
        this.x *= ratio;
        this.y *= ratio;
    }

    get theta() { return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x); }

}

var q = new p();
> q
{x: 1, y: 1}
> q.r = 6
> q.theta
```