# mongoose dynamic condition push returned as [object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add a dynamic condition in node.js through mongoose,

```
var date_and_cond = { $and: [] };
date_and_cond.$and.push({"rec_date": {$lt: "2018-08-08"}})
console.log(date_and_cond)
```

I expect the above to print

> { '$and': [ { rec_date: {$lt: "2018-08-08"}

, so mongoose can execute that as a query but what I get is

> { '$and': [ { rec_date: [Object] } ] }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '\[Object\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)

Comment: You can access it from  console.log(date_and_cond.$and[0].rec_date)

Comment: thans @Luca, I am taking in JSON.stringify from that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log object details simply use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

replace your `console.log(date_and_cond)` by `console.log(JSON.stringify(date_and_cond))`.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clear duplicates, instead flag it as such