# Why is there no data in my POST request response?

Tags: express, post, axios

I'm making a post request to a route i set up using express:

```
todolists.post('/getTodoLists', (req, res) => {
  TodoList.findOne({
    userEmail: req.body.userEmail
  })
    .then(todolist => {
      if (!todolist) {
        res.status(404).send()
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(todolist)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send(err)
    })
})
```

When i use the following code to retrieve data from the database, all i get in my console is 'object Object'

```
axios
  .post('todo-lists/getTodoLists', {
      userEmail: this.userEmail
   })
     .then(res => {
        console.log('response from gettodoLists' + res)
        this.todolist = res
        console.log(this.todolist)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

When i use Postman to make a request to the same route with the same request data i get all of the data that i expect to recieve.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is what i get from Postman

```
{
    "_id": "5caca1498accb128c8974d56",
    "title": "todolist1",
    "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
    "todos": [
        {
            "_id": "5caca1498accb128c8974d57",
            "description": "Get this done",
            "completed": true
        }
    ],
    "dateDue": "2019-04-07T18:24:31.207Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is what i get in my console when i console log the response

```
response from gettodoLists[object Object]
```

Comment: You probably need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the data from the response object to get the body seen in Postman.

```
axios.post('todo-lists/getTodoLists', {
      userEmail: this.userEmail
   })
     .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

The response is the full response containing headers and so on