# How to log requests and responses while using request module in node.js?

Tags: node.js, request

How do I force request.js to log requests completely?

Now some parts of the request are obscured by '[Object]' literals:

```
REQUEST { uri: 'https://example.org',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: 
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  json: 
   { foo: 
      { bar: [Object]},
  callback: [Function] }
```

I enable logging via `NODE_DEBUG='request'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '\[Object\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)

Comment: @1556089774 Thanks! I wouldn't call it duplicate but one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882441/694770) was helpful: `require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth=null`