# How can I see full recursive log on VS Code console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, console.log

WHen I want to show a log below,

```
MyClass { child: MyClass { child: MyClass { child: MyClass {  } } } }
```

VS Code console show

```
MyClass { child: [MyClass] }
```

How can I disable this feature and see a full log like first example?

For example, on Google Chrome, I can open detail with clicking triangle mark. (I don't require such a convenience feature to VS Code console, but just want to see full JSON style log)

Comment: you can use util insect to show full log.
https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '\[Object\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)