# How to get more data with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, discord.js

when I do this:

```js
const uuidapi = await axios.get('https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=mykey&name=' + args[1]);
console.log(uuidapi);
```

I get this response from Axios:

https://paste.menudocs.org/paste/7vppu

So my question is: How do I get the Data after "socialMedia"? Heres how `socialMedia` looks like:

```js
"socialMedia": {
          "links": {
            "YOUTUBE": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1L7H9qQyB2zZgt-1XUv6jA",
            "DISCORD": "Altpapier#4847"
        }
    }
```

Why does it say `socialMedia: [Object]`, and how do I get more than this?
I can't use `const { data } = await axios.get(URL);` because I want to get 2 URL responses with the complete data.
I also want to be able to safe for example the DISCORD Name Altpapier#4847 how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

All the data is already here, it's just the formatting of console.log that's not printing every nested object.
If you replace

```
 console.log(uuidapi);
```

by

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(uuidapi));
```

it will work better

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '[Object]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)

you can use `console.dir( yourObject, { depth: null } )`

Comment: Ok thank you, and how can I save this into a const?

Comment: but my problem is, how can I get the Discord Name