# console.log returns [Object] when object is in multiple other objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, javascript-objects

When I have a lot of objects together and I run it using nodejs in cmd It says the [Object] instead of the actual contents of the object.

here is an example from my command prompt [image: example of problem]

```js
myObject = {
  '698045139763069009':{ users: { '560433156377804828': {name: "mark", age: "28"}},info: {} }
}
console.log(myObject);
```

code here ^^^

same thing happens with an array

```js
myObject = {
  '698045139763069009':{ users: { '560433156377804828': ["mark", 28]},info: {} }
}
console.log(myObject);
```

[image: example]

and a screen shot ^^^

help would be appreciated!
thanks

Comment: please show your code

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj),,4)`

Comment: @brk made the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your console doesn't print nested objects.

Change `console.log(someObject)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject))`.

Note that it will give error if the object is cyclic / has circular references.

Comment: Makes sense, because I can still retrieve and put in data. I can also do `console.log(myObject.users)` and see that all the data is still there

Comment: `console.log(myObject.users)` may not print complete `users` object if it has nesting as well so better to do `stringify`.

Answer (score 2):

It's to make the output more readable.

If you want to print the whole object use `util.inspect()` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object) or use `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this (and which uses `util.inspect()`), that will also display nested objects, is `console.dir()`.

Consider below example:

```
  {
    fieldName: 'price_point',
    value: [ 'priced at 25 dollars' ],
    entityValue: [ [Object] ] <----- (this annoying thing here)
  }
```

TURNS THIS INTO

```
{
  fieldName: 'price_point',
  value: [ 'priced at 25 dollars' ],
  entityValue: [ { number: 25, units: 'Dollar' } ] <--- (to this!)
}
```

`JSON.stringify()` DOES NOT show nested arrays and objects.

Comment: Worth mentioning that console.dir takes second argument and to ensure all levels of nested things are printed out, this is how:
`console.dir(myNestedObject, { depth: null })`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my console doesn't print nested arrays or objects. Thanks for all the help!

It's to make it more readable when working with large amounts of nested arrays and objects.