# Error [object object] to JSON: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting this error

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'history' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'previousData' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    --- index 0 closes the circle
```

for these code lines. Need help in understanding the error as well as rectifying it.

```
const data = req.payload['profileData'];
data.history = {
        lastUpdated: [currenttimestamp],
        previousData: [data]
};
```

If I `JSON.stringify(data)` after this I get the above error. I'm also getting the error if I save this in database. If I `console.log(data)` directly, I get `[object object]` response. (I don't understand this response too. Why is it giving an array of objects, when the the payload itself is a JSON.)
`req.payload['profileData']` is of this sort:

```
{
  "color": "#A020F0",
  "name": "Eggplant",
  "scientificName": "Solanum melongena"
}
```

Is there a way to directly assign the `data` to `previousData` without de-structuring?

Comment: You have a reference to `data` inside `data.history.previousData`. So, when you stringify it will throw an error. You could probably save history in another place or create a clone `previousData: [{ ...data }]`.

Comment: I did the latter and it solved my problem :) 
Can you also answer this part? "If I console.log(data) directly, I get [object object] response..."

Comment: something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))` or you can refer to these [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '\[Object\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276) and [console.log returns \[Object\] when object is in multiple other objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788830)

Comment: No I meant why do I get [object object] when I console.log(data)?