# Why console.table prints (with toString) only limited elements at depth level 2

Tags: javascript, console.log

The output of following js script doesn't print toString() version of object if it has more than 2 elements.

```
let printMe_1 = [{
    "A": "a",
    "F": {
        "J": "j",
        "K": "k",
        "L" : "l"
    },
    "G": {
        "J": "j",
        "K": "k",
    }
}]

console.table(printMe_1);
```

Console output:

[image]

And here is the reference to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Comment: Funny enough in reviewing the specifications for this it looks like there are none. `TODO: This will need a good algorithm.`  https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#table Mozilla doesn't define behavior for this either https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table so seems its just up to the browser implementation currently.

Comment: You could try `JSON.stringify()` or [`console.dir` with depth option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object)

Comment: @asawyer exactly! I did look up for it too! I didn't add it in my question because I hope some one is better than me at googling :)

Comment: @SNag yes I did, but it does give the table output and stringfy() makes me loose the dynamic nature of object

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Firefox 81.0 browser console. All levels of `F` show up.

[image: console.table Firefox 81.0]

In Chrome 85.0 and in Edge Chromium 85.0 the table doesn't list the entries but the object gets printed separately anyway.

[image: console.table Chrome 85.0 / Edge Chromium 85.0]

Node 14.5 doesn't print it, as you've rightfully captured.

[image: console.table Node 14.5]

As per [@asawyer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177776/why-console-table-prints-with-tostring-only-limited-elements-at-depth-level-2#comment113488418_64177776) it seems this is left to the browser's/Node's implementation.

Alternatively, you can try `JSON.stringify()` or [console.dir with depth option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534731/979621).