# How to assign an object /array to another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am working on a function that takes in a list  like this:

```js
const payload = [
    [1, 2],
    [1,2,3],
    {
        name: 'sandra',
        age: 20,
        email: 'sandra@xyz.com'
    }
]
```

and returns an object like this:

```js
{
  name: 'return payload',
  response: [ 
    { arr: [1, 2] }, 
    { arr: [1, 2, 3] }, 
    { arr: {
      name: 'sandra',
      age: 20,
      email: 'sandra@xyz.com'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the function I have:

```js
const returnPayload = (arr) => {
  let response = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      response.push({arr: arr[i]})
    }
    return {"name": "return payload", "response": response}
}

returnPayload(payload);
console.log(returnPayload(payload))
```

and this is what it currently returns:

```js
{
  name: 'return payload',
  response: [ { arr: [Array] }, { arr: [Array] }, { arr: [Object] } ]
}
```

I have checked several solutions online and the recommendations are to pass the returning object into `JSON.stringify(obj)`, but I am looking for a neater and easier-to-read alternative. The JSON method returns this:

```
{"name":"return payload","response":[{"arr":[1,2]},{"arr":[1,2,3]},{"arr":{"name":"sandra","age":20,"email":"sandra@xyz.com"}}]}
```

*Pls forgive the title, I'm not sure how to describe this issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to map the array and return an object containing each item in the callback:

```js
const payload = [
    [1, 2],
    [1,2,3],
    {
        name: 'sandra',
        age: 20,
        email: 'sandra@xyz.com'
    }
];

const result = {
  name: 'return payload',
  response: payload.map(item => ({ arr: item }))
};
console.log(result);
```

(but the `arr` property is not necessarily an array, as you can see by the 3rd item - consider a more informative property name, perhaps?)

Comment: Yeah, this is just a sample, not the original function. I use a more descriptive name in the main code.

Comment: For some reason, your suggestion runs fine here, but not on vscode or repl.

Comment: I just tried it in VSCode and it ran just fine. What exactly is the problem you're running into?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. On vscode, I am still getting the same response format as in my question:

`{name: 'return payload', response: [ { arr: [Array] }, { arr: [Array] }, { arr: [Object] } ]}`.

Comment: That's just the Node console display, the output is still what you want. Node is just trying to be helpful by hiding deeply nested structures.

Comment: Oh I see. Is it possible to prevent Node from doing that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object though if I were you, I wouldn't bother with trying to get sconsole.log`s to display prettily, just *do what you need to do* with the data instead, and it'll work

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When an answer helps you, you can consider upvoting or marking it as Accepted to indicate the issue is resolved :)

Comment: yeah, I upvoted the comment with the link you shared. The `util` worked.

Comment: I mean *my* answer.. but if you didn't think it's helpful, that's OK too

Answer (score 1):

if by "easy-to-read" you mean how to see the result, you can continue with `JSON.stringify()` but add an additional argument for spacing.

```js
const payload = [
    [1, 2],
    [1,2,3],
    {
        name: 'sandra',
        age: 20,
        email: 'sandra@xyz.com'
    }
]

const returnPayload = (arr) => {
  let response = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      response.push({arr: arr[i]})
    }
    return {"name": "return payload", "response": response}
}

returnPayload(payload);
console.log(JSON.stringify(returnPayload(payload), null, 3))
```

Comment: Yeah this works but I will be using a larger array and the return value will be a lot more than what is in my question. I'm looking for a way to make the results look like this:
`{ arr: [1, 2, 3], arr: [1,2,3,4] }`. So it's readable

Comment: if you only want to read the `arr` key's value, why not adding a `console.log(JSON.stringify({arr: arr[i]}))` in the for-loop?

Comment: I'm not just trying to read the key values, I want them to be returned when the function is called. But I think I'll just go with the `JSON.stringify`method  since it works.