# How can I access multiply nested sub objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, nested, subobject

I have a larger code which handles and sorts data. In it I want to work with objects to keep it easier and better structured. I have multiple categories and all of them have different nested subobjects, which I have trouble accessing writing/reading.
I searched on the web, w3schools but couldn't find my mistake, so sry for this entry level question!

I wrote a test function to better understand objects!

```
function test(){
  var report, time, name, date, value;
  report = 'Income Statement';
  time = 'Annually';
  name = 'Revenue';
  date = '2017';
  value = '10000000';
  data = {}
  data[report] = {}
  data[report][time] = {}
  data[report][time][name] = {}
  data[report][time][name][date] = value;
  console.log(data);
}
```

As to my understanding what this code does is:
-create an empty object data
-create an empty subobject report
-create an empty subsubobject time
-create an empty subsubsubobject name
-gives the subsubsubobject name a key/value pair date:value
(at least that was my intention to do)

First I tried to skip creating empty objects and directly fill data{} with:
data = {}
data[report][time][name][date] = value;  but he seems to cannot set properties to this.
So I created like above coded first empty subobjects for all subcategories, is this really necessary or am I falling for a simple syntax mistake?

However he still doesn't log me the desired output which would be:

```
{ 'Income Statement': { Annually: { Revenue: {2017:10000000} } } }
```

and instead gives me:

```
{ 'Income Statement': { Annually: { Revenue: [Object] } } }
```

Simply put.. what am I doing wrong? :D

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!
Best regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object

Comment: It does work for me. Your console must be shortening the end of your output to make it easier to read. But the structure seems to be what you expected.

Comment: Thanks guys! raina77ow s link helped. Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I pasted same code in JS console and it is giving proper result.

[Screenshot of console with result of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIAGf.png)

Different ways to initialize object

- Static Data

```js
let data = {
  'Income Statement': {
    'Annually': {
      'Revenue': {
        '2017': '10000000'
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector("#data-result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
```

```html
<div id="data-result"></div>
```

- Dynamic Data

```js
var report, time, name, date, value;
report = 'Income Statement';
time = 'Annually';
name = 'Revenue';
date = '2017';
value = '10000000';

let data = {
  [report]: {
    [time]: {
      [name]: {
        [date]: value
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector("#object-result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
```

```html
<div id="object-result"></div>
```

You can also consider different ways to store same data.

Example -

```
let data = [{
  report: 'Income Statement'
  time: 'Annually'
  name: 'Revenue'
  date: '2017'
  value: '10000000'
}]
```

So now, if you want data by date in future you can get that by using filter

```
let data_2017 = data.filter(x => x.date === '2017');
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!
I use google sheets script, and the variables and values will later be assigned automatically, not manually. 
I still get [object] as an output and can't really figure out why.
But thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes problem solved! Thanks!
It seemed like console.log in google sheets limits the output to two layers for sake of overview. With JSON.stringify he prints like intented to. Thank you! Really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct !! I received `{ Income Statement: { Annually: { Revenue: {2017:10000000} } } }` at console as an output with your given code.

Are u trying to save that data in some variable using test() ??
If yes then you need to use `return data` at the end of the definition on the function test instead of `consol.log(data)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
No I don't save anything, it's a quick test to try what works and to see what he gives me in the console.log.
I use google sheets script, and have no idea why he gives me [object] even in other functions with the same code structure..