# Typescript rendering array as [object Object] when using console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an object in typescript "obj". When I run:

```
console.log(obj);
```

It renders as the following in the terminal console:

```
[object Object]
```

It's only after i wrap it in a `JSON.stringify(obj)` method that it renders the object as expected:

```
[{"allowed_values":["true"],"property":"pro1","required":"true"}]
```

What am I missing? Why is the object not being rendered as a JSON when I run "console.log()"?

---

Here is the scenario that captures the issue I am seeing:

```
violation = {"my_properties":[{"allowed_values":[{"Ref":"The bucket's logical resource name"}],"property":"BucketPolicy.Properties.Bucket","required":"true"}],"decision":"deny","message":"Some message.","policy_id":"FT_S3_0004","resource":"MyFirstBucketB8884501","type":"AWS::S3::Bucket","controls":["NIST-800-53-SA-8(2)"]}
console.log(violation)
```

This outputs:

```
{
  my_properties: [
    {
      allowed_values: [Array],
      property: 'BucketPolicy.Properties.Bucket',
      required: 'true'
    }
  ],
  decision: 'deny',
  message: 'Some message.',
  policy_id: 'FT_S3_0004',
  resource: 'MyFirstBucketB8884501',
  type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket',
  controls: [ 'NIST-800-53-SA-8(2)' ]
}
```

(notice that it prints `[Array]` rather than the actual elements in the array).

Comment: JSON !== Object

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof obj);` show?

Comment: @NickParsons object

Comment: @Darth.Vader Make sure you're not concatenating a string with your `obj`. Also, if you import `util` using `const util = require("util");` what does `console.log(obj[util.inspect.custom])` show?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't do what you claim it does. Post a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem and then we can help you find exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @AlexWayne - I just posted a working example with the issue I am seeing. Please check my original question with an updated example..

Comment: Ah yes, node's console.log can abbreviate deeply nested values for brevity in the terminal. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object for solutions to that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you aren't telling us the whole story. I can log the array object just fine using

```
console.log([{"allowed_values":["true"],"property":"pro1","required":"true"}]);
```

What you are seeing will happen, however, if you do something like this:

```
console.log("obj:" + obj);
```

In that case, .toString() is implicitly called in order to append the object to the preceding string. You can do this alternative and it will work:

```
console.log("obj:", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an entire object to a string, and [object Object] is what the console.log outputs when it sees an object. Only if we convert it to a string then the logger will long the string representation of the object.

Comment: The console logs that actual object when it sees an object, not [object Object] -`console.log({x: 1});` shows `{x: 1}`, and not [object Object]