# Scraping Google Maps Results using the hidden API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, cheerio, unirest

I am scraping google maps results with node js using this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=pizza&hl=en&tbm=map&tch=1&pb=!4m8!1m3!1d11281.305980319747!2d-74.0083012!3d40.7455096!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!7i20!8i40!10b1!12m25!1m1!18b1!2m3!5m1!6e2!20e3!6m16!4b1!23b1!26i1!27i1!41i2!45b1!49b1!63m0!67b1!73m0!74i150000!75b1!89b1!105b1!109b1!110m0!10b1!16b1!19m4!2m3!1i360!2i120!4i8!20m65!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m2!2i4!5b1!6m6!1m2!1i86!2i86!1m2!1i408!2i240!7m50!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e8!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e10!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e9!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e10!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e4!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1s!2z!7e81!24m55!1m15!13m7!2b1!3b1!4b1!6i1!8b1!9b1!20b0!18m6!3b1!4b1!5b1!6b1!13b0!14b0!2b1!5m5!2b1!3b1!5b1!6b1!7b1!10m1!8e3!14m1!3b1!17b1!20m4!1e3!1e6!1e14!1e15!24b1!25b1!26b1!29b1!30m1!2b1!36b1!43b1!52b1!54m1!1b1!55b1!56m2!1b1!3b1!65m5!3m4!1m3!1m2!1i224!2i298!89b1!26m4!2m3!1i80!2i92!4i8!30m28!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i0!2m2!1i458!2i768!1m6!1m2!1i974!2i0!2m2!1i1024!2i768!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i0!2m2!1i1024!2i20!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i748!2m2!1i1024!2i768!34m16!2b1!3b1!4b1!6b1!8m4!1b1!3b1!4b1!6b1!9b1!12b1!14b1!20b1!23b1!25b1!26b1!37m1!1e81!42b1!46m1!1e9!47m0!49m1!3b1!50m53!1m49!2m7!1u3!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!3m1!1e1!2m7!1u2!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!2m1!1e1!2m7!1u16!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!16m1!1e1!2m7!1u16!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!16m1!1e2!3m11!1u16!2m4!1m2!16m1!1e1!2s!2m4!1m2!16m1!1e2!2s!3m1!1u2!3m1!1u3!4BIAE!2e2!3m1!3b1!59B!65m0!69i540
```

When you open this URL in your browser, it will download a text file, but I can understand how to parse the data that this text file contains.

And what type of code this text file contains, is it JSON or what I can't understand.

Here is my code:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require("fs");
const unirest = require("unirest");

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://www.google.com/search?q=pizza&hl=en&tbm=map&tch=1&pb=!4m8!1m3!1d11281.305980319747!2d-74.0083012!3d40.7455096!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!7i20!8i40!10b1!12m25!1m1!18b1!2m3!5m1!6e2!20e3!6m16!4b1!23b1!26i1!27i1!41i2!45b1!49b1!63m0!67b1!73m0!74i150000!75b1!89b1!105b1!109b1!110m0!10b1!16b1!19m4!2m3!1i360!2i120!4i8!20m65!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m2!2i4!5b1!6m6!1m2!1i86!2i86!1m2!1i408!2i240!7m50!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e8!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e10!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e9!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e10!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e4!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1s!2z!7e81!24m55!1m15!13m7!2b1!3b1!4b1!6i1!8b1!9b1!20b0!18m6!3b1!4b1!5b1!6b1!13b0!14b0!2b1!5m5!2b1!3b1!5b1!6b1!7b1!10m1!8e3!14m1!3b1!17b1!20m4!1e3!1e6!1e14!1e15!24b1!25b1!26b1!29b1!30m1!2b1!36b1!43b1!52b1!54m1!1b1!55b1!56m2!1b1!3b1!65m5!3m4!1m3!1m2!1i224!2i298!89b1!26m4!2m3!1i80!2i92!4i8!30m28!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i0!2m2!1i458!2i768!1m6!1m2!1i974!2i0!2m2!1i1024!2i768!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i0!2m2!1i1024!2i20!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i748!2m2!1i1024!2i768!34m16!2b1!3b1!4b1!6b1!8m4!1b1!3b1!4b1!6b1!9b1!12b1!14b1!20b1!23b1!25b1!26b1!37m1!1e81!42b1!46m1!1e9!47m0!49m1!3b1!50m53!1m49!2m7!1u3!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!3m1!1e1!2m7!1u2!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!2m1!1e1!2m7!1u16!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!16m1!1e1!2m7!1u16!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!16m1!1e2!3m11!1u16!2m4!1m2!16m1!1e1!2s!2m4!1m2!16m1!1e2!2s!3m1!1u2!3m1!1u3!4BIAE!2e2!3m1!3b1!59B!65m0!69i540";

    const response = await unirest.get(url).headers({
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
    });

    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    fs.writeFileSync("./maps.txt", response.body);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

getData();
```

Comment: I assume you meant "I can't understand" rather than "I can understand". It's a sort of raw JSON with some extra junk added to it. Cheerio is an HTML parser, so that's totally out of the ballpark. The approach would be to try to strip out the junk and parse the JSON. How did you build/obtain this URL? I'd like to see another example so I can get a better sense of the format.

Comment: I got this URL form testing various serp api's in the market like serpapi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73558280/6243352) is in the ballpark, but string replacements that can't differentiate between the real data and the junk to remove seems brittle and unnecessary.

Because there's not that much junk in the response (10 bytes by my count, at least on this particular response--I'll assume similar responses adhere to the same structure), there's a more precise approach.

The first step is to remove the trailing `/*""*/` from the string: `data = data.slice(0, -6)`. The resulting structure is now valid JSON and can be parsed with `JSON.parse`.

The parsed data structure has the following top-level keys, with my summarized annotations for `"d"`, `"e"` and `"u"`:

```
{
  "c": 0,
  "d": "the data payload as a string of length 300256, prefixed by )]}'",
  "e": "6m8XY-2AB_vYkPIPt9mU-A4 (or some other similar id)",
  "p": true,
  "u": "https://www.google.com/search?q=pizza&hl=en... (the full URL echoed)",
}
```

The payload we're mainly interested in is in key `"d"`. It's a giant string that is mostly valid JSON except for a 4 byte junk prefix we can strip out, `)]}'`.

After that, we can `JSON.parse` the rest of `d` to produce a giant sparse nested array with a ton of nulls in it:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12
const fs = require("fs");

const url =
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=pizza&hl=en&tbm=map&tch=1&pb=!4m8!1m3!1d11281.305980319747!2d-74.0083012!3d40.7455096!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!7i20!8i40!10b1!12m25!1m1!18b1!2m3!5m1!6e2!20e3!6m16!4b1!23b1!26i1!27i1!41i2!45b1!49b1!63m0!67b1!73m0!74i150000!75b1!89b1!105b1!109b1!110m0!10b1!16b1!19m4!2m3!1i360!2i120!4i8!20m65!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m2!2i4!5b1!6m6!1m2!1i86!2i86!1m2!1i408!2i240!7m50!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e8!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e10!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e9!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e10!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e10!2b0!3e4!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1s!2z!7e81!24m55!1m15!13m7!2b1!3b1!4b1!6i1!8b1!9b1!20b0!18m6!3b1!4b1!5b1!6b1!13b0!14b0!2b1!5m5!2b1!3b1!5b1!6b1!7b1!10m1!8e3!14m1!3b1!17b1!20m4!1e3!1e6!1e14!1e15!24b1!25b1!26b1!29b1!30m1!2b1!36b1!43b1!52b1!54m1!1b1!55b1!56m2!1b1!3b1!65m5!3m4!1m3!1m2!1i224!2i298!89b1!26m4!2m3!1i80!2i92!4i8!30m28!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i0!2m2!1i458!2i768!1m6!1m2!1i974!2i0!2m2!1i1024!2i768!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i0!2m2!1i1024!2i20!1m6!1m2!1i0!2i748!2m2!1i1024!2i768!34m16!2b1!3b1!4b1!6b1!8m4!1b1!3b1!4b1!6b1!9b1!12b1!14b1!20b1!23b1!25b1!26b1!37m1!1e81!42b1!46m1!1e9!47m0!49m1!3b1!50m53!1m49!2m7!1u3!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!3m1!1e1!2m7!1u2!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!2m1!1e1!2m7!1u16!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!16m1!1e1!2m7!1u16!4s!5e1!9s!10m2!16m1!1e2!3m11!1u16!2m4!1m2!16m1!1e1!2s!2m4!1m2!16m1!1e2!2s!3m1!1u2!3m1!1u3!4BIAE!2e2!3m1!3b1!59B!65m0!69i540";

fetch(url, { // Node 18 or install node-fetch
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36",
  }
})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(data => {
    const fullObj = JSON.parse(data.slice(0, -6));
    const payload = JSON.parse(fullObj.d.slice(4));

    console.log(payload); // truncated to depth 2 by default

    // if you want to log the full "d" payload
    //    (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882441/6243352)
    // require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;
    // console.log(payload);

    return fs.promises.writeFile(
      "google-data.json",

      // skip null, 2 if you want to compress
      JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2)
    );
  })
;
```

The written file will contain the prettified `"d"` payload. If you want the whole response with metadata and the prefixes stripped, try `fullObj.d = payload;`, then write `fullObj` to file as above.

Here's a dump of the parsed `"d"` truncated by Node's default `require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth` which is 2 on my v18.4.0:

```js
[
  [
    'pizza',
    [
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array]
    ],
    null,
    1,
    null,
    [ '1662482659245', [Array] ],
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    0
  ],
  [
    [ 11281.30607800397, -74.00830120147852, 40.74550902413187 ],
    null,
    [ 1024, 768 ],
    13.1
  ],
  [],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  '4ngXY9u_IfXYkPIP45yLoAk',
  null,
  [
    [
      [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array]
    ]
  ],
  [ [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ] ],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [ [ [Array] ], [ [Array] ] ],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [
    null,
    null,
    [ '0ahUKEwjbuLvCzoD6AhV1LEQIHWPOApQQnVUIqwYoAA' ],
    [ [Array], '0ahUKEwjbuLvCzoD6AhV1LEQIHWPOApQQzzgIrAYoAQ' ],
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    'IAE='
  ],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [ 9 ],
  null,
  [ [ null, [Array], [Array], 'IAE=' ] ],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  'Q2dBd0Fn',
  null,
  [ 2 ],
  0,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [ 1 ]
]
```

I have no idea how to actually use this data or how the URL was created, so a comment with an API/consumption reference for future visitors would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Its json but first you should clean it. For the file from the example URL:

1. Remove last `/*""*/`
2. Remove heading `{"c":0,"d":")]}'`
3. remove all `\n`
4. Replace `\"` by simple `"`
5. Split by `","e":"` and keep first part.

After that, the content of the file is a valid JSON string:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let file = fs.readFileSync("f.txt").toString();
file = file.replace('/*""*/', "");
file = file.replace('{"c":0,"d":")]}\'', "");
file = file.replaceAll('\\"', '"');
file = file.replaceAll("\\n", "");
file = file.split('","e":"')[0]
const fl = JSON.parse(file);
console.log(fl)
```

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/vn1tSDiY, but it returned me an error replaceAll() is not a function. And if I try by using file, then I get file.replaceAll() is not a function.

Comment: Solved that error, but now Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 2.
I think replaceAll is not working.