# Vitest: How to increase depth of console.log?

Tags: vue.js, vitest

I am using Vitest and in my testing I want to console log output something. But If I log like this:

```
console.log({ a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } });
```

I get this output:

```
{ a: { b: { c: [Object] } } }
```

The same happens with console.dir(). Is there any way to increase the depth of object logging in Vitest? I am working around it with JSON.stringify() but it would be helpful to have it formatted like the default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object):

Using [250R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729284/16476610) answer:

> You need to use [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):
>
> ```js
> const util = require('util')
>
> console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {showHidden: false, depth: null, colors: true}))
>
> // alternative shortcut
> console.log(util.inspect(myObject, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
> ```
>
> Outputs:
>
> ```js
> { a: 'a',  b: { c: 'c', d: { e: 'e', f: { g: 'g', h: { i: 'i' } } } } }
> ```

Or you can find other ways of doing the same thing on that question page; you can pick whatever you feel comfortable with.

---

But if I were you, I'd go with:

```js
console.dir(myObject, { depth: null });
```

because of the following:

1. Built-in function from `console`, so no dependencies are needed.
2. Support colorization.
3. No hard coded functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without additional lib like this:

```
function logAllParameters(obj, prefix = '') {
for (let key in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    logAllParameters(obj[key], prefix + key + '.');
  } else {
    console.log(prefix + key + ':', obj[key]);
  }
 }
}

const obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } } };
logAllParameters(obj);
```