# Node.js: How to get toString() to print object details

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree, tostring, console.log

Consider the following code:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data = null, parent = null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = [];
  }

  appendChild(data) {
    this.children.push(new Node(data, this.root));
    return this.root;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.data;
  }
}

class NTree {
  constructor(data) {
    this.root = null;
  }

  addRoot(data) {
    this.root = new Node(data);
  }

  find(data) {
    if (this.root.data === data) {
      return this.root;
    }
  }

  appendChild(data) {
    this.root.appendChild(data);
  }

  toString() {
    console.log(this.root);
  }
}

const t = new NTree();
t.addRoot(1);
t.appendChild(2);
t.appendChild(3);
t.appendChild(4);

console.log(t);
```

The outputs looks as follows:

```bash
NTree {
  root: Node { data: 1, parent: null, children: [ [Node], [Node], [Node] ] }
}
```

How can I convert the above output to this:

```bash
NTree {
  root: Node { data: 1, parent: null, children: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }
}
```

Comment: try `t.push(2)` instead of `t.appendChild(2)`

Comment: @Layhout and how does it help?

Comment: Node only logs 2 levels deep before it starts displaying placeholders. If you want to log more,  then you can use one of these options [How can I get the full object in Node.js's console.log(), rather than '\[Object\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10729276)

Comment: Why do you want to print the root node in a kind of object notation, while you want to print the children as integers. What if those children have children? Secondly, you ask about `toString()`, but that is never called in your code. BTW, the `appendChild` methond on the `Node` class references an unexisting `this.root`. Your parent links are not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(t.root, null, 4));
```