# How to display the whole object in vscode terminal when facing <x more bytes...>

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am `console.log()` a buffer inside vsCode using Nodejs:

```js
const firstBuf = Buffer.alloc(1024);
console.log(firstBuf)
```

The result:

```
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... 974 more bytes>
```

How to display the first x buffer in the terminal? (x is the numbers of buffer that I want to display)
?

Comment: show exactly how to reproduce the behaviour you're seeing (a [mre]). I suspect this will end up being a duplicate of something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/10729276/11107541

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(firstBuf.toJSON().data.toString())
```

First convert **Buffer** data in *JOSN*
that looks like this:

```js
{
  type: 'Buffer',
  data: [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    ... 924 more items
  ]
}
```

then convert **data** into *String*.