# Accessing nested array within a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am stuck trying to get to the array within this object. It is showing them as `[Object object]` every time I try to print a value from the nested array.

This is the object:

```
{"current":true,
 "values_remaining":443,
 "color":"blue",
 "type":"1",
 "time":20444,
 "category":"story",
 "id":"kflaghe",
 "score":1270,

 "arr":[
        {"num":293,"person":"pera","val":"K3344"},
        {"num":407,"person":"perb","val":"B5637"},
        {"num":256,"person":"perc","val":"J4526"}
       ]
}
```

I was accessing the keys and values prior to the "arr" by using

```
for (const key in data) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
}
```

I found the above approach here: https://flexiple.com/javascript/loop-through-object-javascript

When I print everything up to the array it will show up properly as:
`score: 1270`

But when it gets to the arr part, it prints as:
`arr: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

I researched and tried to access the array based on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-json-array/

However, it is not recognizing the objects contained within the array. It prints `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` no matter what I do.

I tried to isolate that arr and one of the number values by using the following:

```
var arr= (`${data[key]}`);
var arrValue = arr[0];
console.log(arrValue.num);
```

it printed: `undefined`

How can I access these key value pairs contained within the array (the `arr` section)?

Comment: Please read the tag descritptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag description contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_ Don't use the term _"JSON"_ for JavaScript objects or arrays. It's not the same. Have you tried to serialize the arrays (convert the JavaScript objects to JSON)? You can use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: thats what happens when you try to print objects concat to a string it prints the .toString() version which gives object Object

Comment: The issue is that you coerce the array to a string. Instead of `console.log(\`${key}: ${data[key]\`})` you need to do `console.log(\`${key}: \`, data[key])`. Note that the array of objects is passed as **separate argument** so it can be displayed properly without being forced into a (bad) string representation first. This is important for most complex data when you log it (also `Error` objects btw, which will otherwise lose their stack).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with how you're accessing your data. When you run code on Node, it just doesn't print out objects inside [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

You can force node to print it out by stringifying an object. You can test your code with the following code.

```
for (const key in data) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${JSON.stringify(data?.[key], null, 2)}`);
}
```

Also, you also mentioned that you are getting an `undefined` value when you try to isolate the array and access the `num` property inside it. That is most likely happening because you are trying to access the `num` property in one of your non-array properties. If you check the datatype of the value first, you should be able to do what you want.

Below is how I would approach accessing both the array data and the non-array data in loop.

```
    for (const key in data) {
        const value = data[key]; // can be either an array or string or a number

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            for (const arrayItem of value) {
                console.log(arrayItem)
            }
        }

        if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
            console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I copy pasted the code into Typescript playground and it ran just fine. It displayed object object as he said.

Comment: But it's related to string concatenation. The object is correctly printed without string concatenation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvARMArgJ3wFMwosAuKfXIgGgCgYsA3BAGxogH1iBbBAJZghAcwoAWcQGYGTUGxD4KWAEYciWWVigBPAA4byWAIybG2gb0MAmAAyTxW4EiIjFO5dHdmmAuMoBrADM2BBEACw0tCFBiCmNrAHZbBnMEQgoAbUYYXLzMLDBcXgprAE4ZLAN8CHBlaoRNFnZlAGkpKUksAF9ZfLzsIpLycVtE2iqiGrqjapUm1jZlACEAVgA2KUSevv6CodKNierasHqp4AWWowApcVXrdZ6c-oBdem6Abnp6UEgQNhEAB0ChEAApEMgAJSfIA

Comment: Thank you so much - I had tried stringify and I must have put it at the wrong level or something because it was turning the [Object object] into a string! I was really stuck and I appreciate your help! I was going through article after article with no success until your answer. :)

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, the objected was being interpolated as a string for the console log. I missed that. My bad. But it is true that the ```[object]``` thing happens for deeply nested objects when you try to console log them.

Comment: That's only because the inspect depth is limited by default. You can change that using [`util.inspect.defaultOptions.depth`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectdefaultoptions). Set it to `null` for infinite depth. (You can also do that on a case by case basis by manually calling `util.inspect` with the desired options instead of relying on `console.log` calling it for you). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object).

Comment: I fixed the answer.

Comment: It's not only Node and it's not related to printing. It's the concatenation. You don't need `console.log` to reproduce the problem.

Comment: its a template string, no concatenation is happening.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the conversion.