How to display elements in an array to the console using JavaScript?
How do I display each of the elements in detail in the following array in the VS Code console using JavaScript?
var myList = [["cereal", 3], ["milk", 2], ["bananas", 3], ["juice", 2], ["eggs", 6]];

My attempt:
console.log(myList);

Console displayed:
(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]


console.log(myList.toString());? or (better) console.log(JSON.stringify(myList));

There is a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object
