# Client and Server Interaction

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, node.js, client-server

So I'm developing an app that shows items as lists and you can insert more items onto the page via post. But I'm stuck on one problem. I do not understand how am I suppose to connect the client to the server via JSON files.

The main page reads from a JSON file and displays all the items. That part is fully covered but thereafter I need help.

I am not sure on how I'm suppose to input data in a JSON file (I was able to read the input via Angular but still have to input them into a JSON) and that file is then magically sent to the server were the server reads the input and sends back another JSON file with updated list of items to be displayed on the main page.

How do I approach this ?

For this app I also used JQuery and Node.js

Comment: most would not use json files but would use a database

Comment: Is the answer here what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11677276/2743458

Comment: Ahh okay so that's how I can input them into a json file !! Thanks @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: @charlietfl it wasn't my decision to use json but the professor's 
basically he wanted the server and client to only connect through json . . . the server does have a database of its own though

Comment: `connect through json` doesn't necessarily mean using static json files though