# how to handle json and write to a file in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Now I have code like this api call, the social network vk.com:

```
// Setup
var fs = require('fs');
var VK = require('vksdk');

var vk = new VK({
    'appId': ********,
    'appSecret': '*****************',
    'language': 'ru'
});


vk.oldRequest("photos.get", {
    owner_id: "-28445240",
    album_id: "wall",
    rev: "1",
    extended: "1",
    version: "5.40",
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

In the console output json. How to write it to a file.

Comment: Well, did you try `fs.writeFile(filename, data, [encoding], [callback])` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js

Comment: after fs.writeFile , my file contain:    [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `JSON.stringify(anyObject)`  to `fs.writeFile` in order to save an object to a file, otherwise, you will get the string `[object Object]` (the result of `Object.prototype.toString()`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

- [Convert the object to a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670752/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-node-js) with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). You got `[object Object]` because that's how JS coerces objects to strings.
- [Write it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) with [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), function(err) {
    if(err) { return console.log(err); }
});
```