# Write JSON object into a new file as string but in pretty format using axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have data in rethinkdb as following:
[image]

but now when I do this:

```
await axios.post(config.baseURL + '/save-menu', {
  filename: rawConfigs[0].repoSettings[0].BaseURL + '/public/log.md' ,
  text:JSON.stringify(job.log),
  type: 'file'
  }).catch((e) => {
   console.log(e)
  )
```

The result is stored as this:
[image]

I want it as pretty as it looks in rethinkdb.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670892/3461055

Comment: Can you paste your JSON data as text instead of screenshot?

Comment: @ArifKhan no its different because stringify does'nt work for me.

Comment: You need to use `text: JSON.stringify(job.log, null, 4)` , check [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: TY @ArifKhan `text: JSON.stringify(job.log, null, 4) ` worked as well the pacakge json-format